# What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, character-encoding

When I open `cmd.exe` on Windows, what encoding is it using?

How can I check which encoding it is currently using? 
Does it depend on my regional setting or are there any environment
variables to check?

What happens when you type a file with a certain encoding?
Sometimes I get garbled characters (because of incorrect encoding) and
sometimes it kind of works. 
However,
I don't trust anything as long as I don't know what's going on.
Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 443, accepted):

Yes, it’s frustrating—sometimes `type` and other programs
print gibberish, and sometimes they do not.

First of all, Unicode characters will only display [if the
current console font contains the characters](https://web.archive.org/web/20130827001400/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/99795). So use
a TrueType font like Lucida Console instead of the default Raster Font.

But if the console font doesn’t contain the character you’re trying to display,
you’ll see question marks instead of gibberish. When you get gibberish,
there’s more going on than just font settings.

When programs use standard C-library I/O functions like `printf`, **the
program’s output encoding must match the console’s output encoding**, or
you will get gibberish. `chcp` shows and sets the current codepage. All
output using standard C-library I/O functions is treated as if it is in the
codepage displayed by `chcp`.

Matching the program’s output encoding with the console’s output encoding
can be accomplished in two different ways:

- A program can get the console’s current codepage using `chcp` or
  [`GetConsoleOutputCP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683169(v=vs.85).aspx), and configure itself to output in that encoding, or
- You or a program can set the console’s current codepage using `chcp` or
  [`SetConsoleOutputCP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686036(v=vs.85).aspx) to match the default output encoding of the program.

However, programs that use Win32 APIs can write UTF-16LE strings directly
to the console with
[`WriteConsoleW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401(v=vs.85).aspx).
This is the only way to get correct output without setting codepages. And
even when using that function, if a string is not in the UTF-16LE encoding
to begin with, a Win32 program must pass the correct codepage to
[`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx).
Also, `WriteConsoleW` will not work if the program’s output is redirected;
more fiddling is needed in that case.

`type` works some of the time because it checks the start of each file for
a  UTF-16LE [Byte Order Mark
(BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), i.e. the bytes `0xFF 0xFE`.
If it finds such a
mark, it displays the Unicode characters in the file using `WriteConsoleW`
regardless of the current codepage. But when `type`ing any file without a
UTF-16LE BOM, or for using non-ASCII characters with any command
that doesn’t call `WriteConsoleW`—you will need to set the
console codepage and program output encoding to match each other.

---

How can we find this out?

Here’s a test file containing Unicode characters:

```
ASCII     abcde xyz
German    äöü ÄÖÜ ß
Polish    ąęźżńł
Russian   абвгдеж эюя
CJK       你好
```

Here’s a Java program to print out the test file in a bunch of different
Unicode encodings. It could be in any programming language; it only prints
ASCII characters or encoded bytes to `stdout`.

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Foo {

    private static final String BOM = "\ufeff";
    private static final String TEST_STRING
        = "ASCII     abcde xyz\n"
        + "German    äöü ÄÖÜ ß\n"
        + "Polish    ąęźżńł\n"
        + "Russian   абвгдеж эюя\n"
        + "CJK       你好\n";

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception
    {
        String[] encodings = new String[] {
            "UTF-8", "UTF-16LE", "UTF-16BE", "UTF-32LE", "UTF-32BE" };

        for (String encoding: encodings) {
            System.out.println("== " + encoding);

            for (boolean writeBom: new Boolean[] {false, true}) {
                System.out.println(writeBom ? "= bom" : "= no bom");

                String output = (writeBom ? BOM : "") + TEST_STRING;
                byte[] bytes = output.getBytes(encoding);
                System.out.write(bytes);
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("uc-test-"
                    + encoding + (writeBom ? "-bom.txt" : "-nobom.txt"));
                out.write(bytes);
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output in the default codepage? **Total garbage!**

```
Z:\andrew\projects\sx\1259084>chcp
Active code page: 850

Z:\andrew\projects\sx\1259084>java Foo
== UTF-8
= no bom
ASCII     abcde xyz
German    ├ñ├Â├╝ ├ä├û├£ ├ƒ
Polish    ─à─Ö┼║┼╝┼ä┼é
Russian   ð░ð▒ð▓ð│ð┤ðÁðÂ ÐìÐÄÐÅ
CJK       õ¢áÕÑ¢
= bom
´╗┐ASCII     abcde xyz
German    ├ñ├Â├╝ ├ä├û├£ ├ƒ
Polish    ─à─Ö┼║┼╝┼ä┼é
Russian   ð░ð▒ð▓ð│ð┤ðÁðÂ ÐìÐÄÐÅ
CJK       õ¢áÕÑ¢
== UTF-16LE
= no bom
A S C I I           a b c d e   x y z
 G e r m a n         õ ÷ ³   ─ Í ▄   ▀
 P o l i s h         ♣☺↓☺z☺|☺D☺B☺
 R u s s i a n       0♦1♦2♦3♦4♦5♦6♦  M♦N♦O♦
 C J K               `O}Y
 = bom
 ■A S C I I           a b c d e   x y z
 G e r m a n         õ ÷ ³   ─ Í ▄   ▀
 P o l i s h         ♣☺↓☺z☺|☺D☺B☺
 R u s s i a n       0♦1♦2♦3♦4♦5♦6♦  M♦N♦O♦
 C J K               `O}Y
 == UTF-16BE
= no bom
 A S C I I           a b c d e   x y z
 G e r m a n         õ ÷ ³   ─ Í ▄   ▀
 P o l i s h        ☺♣☺↓☺z☺|☺D☺B
 R u s s i a n      ♦0♦1♦2♦3♦4♦5♦6  ♦M♦N♦O
 C J K              O`Y}
= bom
■  A S C I I           a b c d e   x y z
 G e r m a n         õ ÷ ³   ─ Í ▄   ▀
 P o l i s h        ☺♣☺↓☺z☺|☺D☺B
 R u s s i a n      ♦0♦1♦2♦3♦4♦5♦6  ♦M♦N♦O
 C J K              O`Y}
== UTF-32LE
= no bom
A   S   C   I   I                       a   b   c   d   e       x   y   z
   G   e   r   m   a   n                   õ   ÷   ³       ─   Í   ▄       ▀
   P   o   l   i   s   h                   ♣☺  ↓☺  z☺  |☺  D☺  B☺
   R   u   s   s   i   a   n               0♦  1♦  2♦  3♦  4♦  5♦  6♦      M♦  N
♦  O♦
   C   J   K                               `O  }Y
   = bom
 ■  A   S   C   I   I                       a   b   c   d   e       x   y   z

   G   e   r   m   a   n                   õ   ÷   ³       ─   Í   ▄       ▀
   P   o   l   i   s   h                   ♣☺  ↓☺  z☺  |☺  D☺  B☺
   R   u   s   s   i   a   n               0♦  1♦  2♦  3♦  4♦  5♦  6♦      M♦  N
♦  O♦
   C   J   K                               `O  }Y
   == UTF-32BE
= no bom
   A   S   C   I   I                       a   b   c   d   e       x   y   z
   G   e   r   m   a   n                   õ   ÷   ³       ─   Í   ▄       ▀
   P   o   l   i   s   h                  ☺♣  ☺↓  ☺z  ☺|  ☺D  ☺B
   R   u   s   s   i   a   n              ♦0  ♦1  ♦2  ♦3  ♦4  ♦5  ♦6      ♦M  ♦N
  ♦O
   C   J   K                              O`  Y}
= bom
  ■    A   S   C   I   I                       a   b   c   d   e       x   y   z

   G   e   r   m   a   n                   õ   ÷   ³       ─   Í   ▄       ▀
   P   o   l   i   s   h                  ☺♣  ☺↓  ☺z  ☺|  ☺D  ☺B
   R   u   s   s   i   a   n              ♦0  ♦1  ♦2  ♦3  ♦4  ♦5  ♦6      ♦M  ♦N
  ♦O
   C   J   K                              O`  Y}
```

However, what if we `type` the files that got saved? They contain the exact
same bytes that were printed to the console.

```
Z:\andrew\projects\sx\1259084>type *.txt

uc-test-UTF-16BE-bom.txt


■  A S C I I           a b c d e   x y z
 G e r m a n         õ ÷ ³   ─ Í ▄   ▀
 P o l i s h        ☺♣☺↓☺z☺|☺D☺B
 R u s s i a n      ♦0♦1♦2♦3♦4♦5♦6  ♦M♦N♦O
 C J K              O`Y}

uc-test-UTF-16BE-nobom.txt


 A S C I I           a b c d e   x y z
 G e r m a n         õ ÷ ³   ─ Í ▄   ▀
 P o l i s h        ☺♣☺↓☺z☺|☺D☺B
 R u s s i a n      ♦0♦1♦2♦3♦4♦5♦6  ♦M♦N♦O
 C J K              O`Y}

uc-test-UTF-16LE-bom.txt


ASCII     abcde xyz
German    äöü ÄÖÜ ß
Polish    ąęźżńł
Russian   абвгдеж эюя
CJK       你好

uc-test-UTF-16LE-nobom.txt


A S C I I           a b c d e   x y z
 G e r m a n         õ ÷ ³   ─ Í ▄   ▀
 P o l i s h         ♣☺↓☺z☺|☺D☺B☺
 R u s s i a n       0♦1♦2♦3♦4♦5♦6♦  M♦N♦O♦
 C J K               `O}Y

uc-test-UTF-32BE-bom.txt


  ■    A   S   C   I   I                       a   b   c   d   e       x   y   z

   G   e   r   m   a   n                   õ   ÷   ³       ─   Í   ▄       ▀
   P   o   l   i   s   h                  ☺♣  ☺↓  ☺z  ☺|  ☺D  ☺B
   R   u   s   s   i   a   n              ♦0  ♦1  ♦2  ♦3  ♦4  ♦5  ♦6      ♦M  ♦N
  ♦O
   C   J   K                              O`  Y}

uc-test-UTF-32BE-nobom.txt


   A   S   C   I   I                       a   b   c   d   e       x   y   z
   G   e   r   m   a   n                   õ   ÷   ³       ─   Í   ▄       ▀
   P   o   l   i   s   h                  ☺♣  ☺↓  ☺z  ☺|  ☺D  ☺B
   R   u   s   s   i   a   n              ♦0  ♦1  ♦2  ♦3  ♦4  ♦5  ♦6      ♦M  ♦N
  ♦O
   C   J   K                              O`  Y}

uc-test-UTF-32LE-bom.txt


 A S C I I           a b c d e   x y z
 G e r m a n         ä ö ü   Ä Ö Ü   ß
 P o l i s h         ą ę ź ż ń ł
 R u s s i a n       а б в г д е ж   э ю я
 C J K               你 好

uc-test-UTF-32LE-nobom.txt


A   S   C   I   I                       a   b   c   d   e       x   y   z
   G   e   r   m   a   n                   õ   ÷   ³       ─   Í   ▄       ▀
   P   o   l   i   s   h                   ♣☺  ↓☺  z☺  |☺  D☺  B☺
   R   u   s   s   i   a   n               0♦  1♦  2♦  3♦  4♦  5♦  6♦      M♦  N
♦  O♦
   C   J   K                               `O  }Y

uc-test-UTF-8-bom.txt


´╗┐ASCII     abcde xyz
German    ├ñ├Â├╝ ├ä├û├£ ├ƒ
Polish    ─à─Ö┼║┼╝┼ä┼é
Russian   ð░ð▒ð▓ð│ð┤ðÁðÂ ÐìÐÄÐÅ
CJK       õ¢áÕÑ¢

uc-test-UTF-8-nobom.txt


ASCII     abcde xyz
German    ├ñ├Â├╝ ├ä├û├£ ├ƒ
Polish    ─à─Ö┼║┼╝┼ä┼é
Russian   ð░ð▒ð▓ð│ð┤ðÁðÂ ÐìÐÄÐÅ
CJK       õ¢áÕÑ¢
```

The *only* thing that works is UTF-16LE file, with a BOM, printed to the
console via `type`.

If we use anything other than `type` to print the file, we get garbage:

```
Z:\andrew\projects\sx\1259084>copy uc-test-UTF-16LE-bom.txt CON
 ■A S C I I           a b c d e   x y z
 G e r m a n         õ ÷ ³   ─ Í ▄   ▀
 P o l i s h         ♣☺↓☺z☺|☺D☺B☺
 R u s s i a n       0♦1♦2♦3♦4♦5♦6♦  M♦N♦O♦
 C J K               `O}Y
         1 file(s) copied.
```

From the fact that `copy CON` does not display Unicode correctly, we can
conclude that the `type` command has logic to detect a UTF-16LE BOM at the
start of the file, and use special Windows APIs to print it.

We can see this by opening `cmd.exe` in a debugger when it goes to `type`
out a file:

[image]

After `type` opens a file, it checks for a BOM of `0xFEFF`—i.e., the bytes
`0xFF 0xFE` in little-endian—and if there is such a BOM, `type` sets an
internal `fOutputUnicode` flag. This flag is checked later to decide
whether to call `WriteConsoleW`.

But that’s the only way to get `type` to output Unicode, and only for files
that have BOMs and are in UTF-16LE. For all other files, and for programs
that don’t have special code to handle console output, your files will be
interpreted according to the current codepage, and will likely show up as
gibberish.

You can emulate how `type` outputs Unicode to the console in your own programs like so:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define UNICODE
#include <windows.h>

static LPCSTR lpcsTest =
    "ASCII     abcde xyz\n"
    "German    äöü ÄÖÜ ß\n"
    "Polish    ąęźżńł\n"
    "Russian   абвгдеж эюя\n"
    "CJK       你好\n";

int main() {
    int n;
    wchar_t buf[1024];

    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    n = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0,
            lpcsTest, strlen(lpcsTest),
            buf, sizeof(buf));

    WriteConsole(hConsole, buf, n, &n, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

This program works for printing Unicode on the Windows console using the
default codepage.

---

For the sample Java program, we can get a little bit of correct output by
setting the codepage manually, though the output gets messed up in weird ways:

```
Z:\andrew\projects\sx\1259084>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

Z:\andrew\projects\sx\1259084>java Foo
== UTF-8
= no bom
ASCII     abcde xyz
German    äöü ÄÖÜ ß
Polish    ąęźżńł
Russian   абвгдеж эюя
CJK       你好
ж эюя
CJK       你好
 你好
好
�
= bom
ASCII     abcde xyz
German    äöü ÄÖÜ ß
Polish    ąęźżńł
Russian   абвгдеж эюя
CJK       你好
еж эюя
CJK       你好
  你好
好
�
== UTF-16LE
= no bom
A S C I I           a b c d e   x y z
…
```

However, a C program that sets a Unicode UTF-8 codepage:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    int c, n;
    UINT oldCodePage;
    char buf[1024];

    oldCodePage = GetConsoleOutputCP();
    if (!SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)) {
        printf("error\n");
    }

    freopen("uc-test-UTF-8-nobom.txt", "rb", stdin);
    n = fread(buf, sizeof(buf[0]), sizeof(buf), stdin);
    fwrite(buf, sizeof(buf[0]), n, stdout);

    SetConsoleOutputCP(oldCodePage);

    return 0;
}
```

does have correct output:

```
Z:\andrew\projects\sx\1259084>.\test
ASCII     abcde xyz
German    äöü ÄÖÜ ß
Polish    ąęźżńł
Russian   абвгдеж эюя
CJK       你好
```

---

The moral of the story?

- `type` can print UTF-16LE files with a BOM regardless of your current codepage
- Win32 programs can be programmed to output Unicode to the console, using
  `WriteConsoleW`.
- Other programs which set the codepage and adjust their output encoding accordingly can print Unicode on the console regardless of what the codepage was when the program started
- For everything else you will have to mess around with `chcp`, and will probably still get weird output.

Comment: One may also want to study the Microsoft-specific extension _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT) which was introduced in VS2008.
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9051543, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12015918, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8(v=vs.90).aspx
Besides obvious portability differences between _setmode() and SetConsoleOutputCP(), there may also be other subtleties and side-effects hidden in both approaches that's not fully understood at first glance.
If andrewdotn could update his answer with any observations about _setmode(fd,_O_U16TEXT), that would be great.

Comment: While this is an excellent answer, it's misleading to say the console supports UTF-16. It's limited to UCS-2, i.e. limited to characters in the basic multilingual plane (BMP). When the Win32 console server (conhost.exe, nowadays) was designed circa 1990, Unicode was a 16-bit standard, so the console screen buffer uses one 16-bit WCHAR per character cell. A UTF-16 surrogate pair prints as two box characters.

Comment: @eryksun - presumably "one 16-bit WCHAR per character cell" also means that the console does not support any form of combining character? Are there other limitations on Unicode in the Windows console?

Comment: @user200783, decomposed form isn't supported; usually one can transform to an NFC equivalent. Also, the console in Western locales doesn't allow mixing full-width and half-width glyphs. Also, when using codepage 65001 (UTF-8), prior to Windows 8 `WriteFile` reports the number of characters written instead of the number of bytes, so buffered writers retry the 'remaining' bytes several times in proportion to the number of non-ASCII characters. Also in 65001, reading non-ASCII characters fails in conhost.exe because it assumes 1 ANSI byte per UTF-16 code when calling `WideCharToMultiByte`.

Comment: @eryksun - Very helpful, thank you. Your two comments do a good job of addressing [one of my recent questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37874063/200783) - if you would like to post them as an answer there, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: The simple demo programs in this answer assume that `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` and C `stdout` are console handles. In practice, to test for a console, check that [`GetConsoleMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683167) succeeds. Also, don't use the C runtime `_isatty` function to check if a low I/O file descriptor is a console; that just checks for a character-mode device, which includes `NUL` among others. Instead, call [`_get_osfhandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks2530z6) and check the handle directly.

Comment: just as a side-note: if you need this for **PHP** CMD-output it might be "codepage 850". so to convert utf8 to CP850 for example, you can do this: `mb_convert_encoding($string, 'CP850', 'UTF-8');`

Comment: This helped me understand the output of Oracle Instant Client on windows command prompt. Thank you!

Comment: I've learned and want to explore a lot of tests, thanks! I have troubles with terminal input sometimes too, so i'll go that way.

Comment: `n = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, lpcsTest, strlen(lpcsTest), buf, sizeof(buf));` This assumed the unprefixed string literal `lpcsTest` is UTF-8 by default, but it is not always the case. In GCC, it is UTF-8, but in MSVC (at least for old version) it based on current code page (independent of how the source file is encoded). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987448/is-there-an-easy-way-to-write-utf-8-octets-in-visual-studio and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/execution-character-set

Answer (score 39):

Type

```
chcp
```

to see your current code page (as Dewfy already said).

Use

```
nlsinfo
```

to see all installed code pages and find out what your code page number means.

You need to have Windows Server 2003 Resource kit installed (works on Windows XP) to use `nlsinfo`.

Comment: Interestingly, `nlsinfo` doesn't appear to exist on my Windows 7.

Comment: `nlsinfo` also doesn't exist on my Windows XP SP3 machine.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I think it comes with Windows Server Resource Kit tools. I've used it a couple of times on my Windows XP SP3 machine earlier and didn't know it wasn't installed by default.

Comment: Ah, that explains why it's there on my Vista machine, where I installed those.

Comment: `nlsinfo` also doesn't exist on Windows 10E machine.

Answer (score 7):

I've been frustrated for long by Windows code page issues, and the C programs portability and localisation issues they cause. The previous posts have detailed the issues at length, so I'm not going to add anything in this respect.

To make a long story short, eventually I ended up writing my own UTF-8 compatibility library layer over the Visual C++ standard C library. Basically this library ensures that a standard C program works right, in any code page, using UTF-8 internally.

This library, called MsvcLibX, is available as open source at https://github.com/JFLarvoire/SysToolsLib. Main features:

- C sources encoded in UTF-8, using normal char[] C strings, and standard C library APIs.
- In any code page, everything is processed internally as UTF-8 in your code, including the main() routine argv[], with standard input and output automatically converted to the right code page.
- All stdio.h file functions support UTF-8 pathnames > 260 characters, up to 64 KBytes actually.
- The same sources can compile and link successfully in Windows using Visual C++ and MsvcLibX and Visual C++ C library, and in Linux using gcc and Linux standard C library, with no need for #ifdef ... #endif blocks.
- Adds include files common in Linux, but missing in Visual C++. Ex: unistd.h
- Adds missing functions, like those for directory I/O, symbolic link management, etc, all with UTF-8 support of course :-).

More details in the [MsvcLibX README on GitHub](https://github.com/JFLarvoire/SysToolsLib/tree/master/C/MsvcLibX), including how to build the library and use it in your own programs.

The [release section](https://github.com/JFLarvoire/SysToolsLib/releases) in the above GitHub repository provides several programs using this MsvcLibX library, that will show its capabilities. Ex: Try my which.exe tool with directories with non-ASCII names in the PATH, searching for programs with non-ASCII names, and changing code pages.

Another useful tool there is the conv.exe program. This program can easily convert a data stream from any code page to any other. Its default is input in the Windows code page, and output in the current console code page. This allows to correctly view data generated by Windows GUI apps (ex: Notepad) in a command console, with a simple command like: `type WINFILE.txt | conv`

This MsvcLibX library is by no means complete, and contributions for improving it are welcome!

Answer (score 6):

Command CHCP shows the current codepage. It has three digits: 8xx and is different from Windows 12xx. So typing a English-only text you wouldn't see any difference, but an extended codepage (like Cyrillic) will be printed wrongly.

Comment: CHCP neither shows only 3 digits nor it is in the 8## format. 437 is for instance a US encoding, and it is the defacto standard on English systems. -- 65001 is a Unicode encoding (If I recall it right it is UTF-8 and 65000 is UTF-7) and can be chosen. Also CMD allows to switch to 1250 code page for instance, but I do not know since when these code pages are selectable. (It is under Win7.)

Answer (score 3):

You can control the code page simply by creating a file %HOMEPATH%\init.cmd.
Mine says:

```
@ECHO OFF
CHCP 65001 > nul
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java I used encoding "IBM850" to write the file. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Short answer – set `cmd.exe` to use *ANSI* encoding by default

*DISCLAIMER. Following any suggestion here is at your own risk.*

Create and run a `.reg` file with a suitable name :
<sup>1</sup>

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
;; https://stackoverflow.com/a/75788701
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"Autorun"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\chcp.com 1252"
```

In case you later change your mind – here is a
`CMD-CodePage-1252-Restore.reg` file :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
;; https://stackoverflow.com/a/75788701
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor]
"Autorun"=-
```

#### 2. Long answer – attempting to answer all your questions

> ##### *When I open `cmd.exe` on Windows, what encoding is it using?*

– By default, `cmd.exe` uses [code page 437](https://www.ascii-codes.com).
This, in my opinion, is an awful choice. 
I suggest instead using your language's *ANSI* code page.
– It's compatible with the *ANSI* encoding in Microsoft's own
native text editor `C:\WINDOWS\System32\notepad.exe`. 
For Western European languages, ANSI means code page 1252,
or *Windows-1252* (CP-1252). 
For other language groups, I've posted a table at the end of
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1744158).

> ##### *How can I check which encoding it is currently using?*

– Run `C:\WINDOWS\System32\chcp.com` :

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 1252
```

The reason it responds `1252` instead of `437` in my case, is that
I've deliberately set `cmd.exe` to use 1252 by default.
As described in my "short" answer above.

> ##### *Does it depend on my regional setting or are there any environment variables to check?*

– Neither. What's relevant in this context is the *language*.
I tried the following: 
*<kbd>WinKey</kbd> + i > Time & Language > Language >
Preferred languages > Add a language*.
I added *Swedish (Sweden)*, and then made sure that under
*Windows display language*, *Swedish* was chosen. 
Finally, I restarted my computer, opened `cmd.exe`, typed `chcp`
and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
The response was `Active code page: 437`.
Thus, although the *Windows display language* changes the language of
Windows, it doesn't seem to affect the code page that `cmd.exe` uses.
<sup>2</sup>

> ##### *What happens when you type a file with a certain encoding?*
>
> ##### *Sometimes I get garbled characters (because of incorrect encoding) and sometimes it kind of works.*

– Yes. That's exactly what you should expect.
As an example, I have a file, `Some-ANSI-chars.txt` which
contains the Swedish letters `å` and `ä`, encoded with the code page
1252, *ANSI* encoded. 
When I `type` the file in `cmd.exe`, the Swedish letters are correctly
printed :

```
C:\stackexchange\stackoverflow\Char-encoding>type Some-ANSI-chars.txt
Sakta men säkert vinner basinkomst mark,
 och det viktigaste just nu är att hålla ihop.
```

But when I make a copy of the file, and [convert](https://superuser.com/a/762475) it to UTF-8,
for every (non-ASCII) Swedish letter, *two garbled* characters are
printed :

```
C:\stackexchange\stackoverflow\Char-encoding>type Some-UTF-8-chars.txt
Sakta men sÃ¤kert vinner basinkomst mark,
 och det viktigaste just nu Ã¤r att hÃ¥lla ihop.
```

As you can see, the two UTF-8 encoded characters `å` and `ä` use
*two bytes each*. 
The `type` command decodes `å` and `ä` to display *two*
nonsensical *one-byte* characters each, namely `Ã¥` and `Ã¤`.
To me, this is not a problem, as I hardly ever `type` the contents
of my text files. 
The only thing that matters, is that my favorite text editor is set to
decode my files as UTF-8.
<sup>3</sup>

> ##### *However, I don't trust anything as long as I don't know what's going on.*

– That's wise of you.
It protects you (I hope) from falling into the trap of using UTF-8
encoding in `cmd.exe`, the culprit being code page 65001.

##### Reasons *not* to use UTF-8 encoding in `cmd.exe`

- There are [serious implementation bugs in Windows's code page
  65001](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490#comment10782008_388500) (2011).
- Code page [65001 … is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490#comment18817211_388500) (2012).
- [`chcp 65001` provides some UTF-8 decoding but it's very
  rudimentary
  and doesn't provide proper input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14109024#comment56860192_14109024) (2016).
- [The Windows console is riddled with bugs when the encoding is set
  to an unsupported multi-byte code page like 65001](https://superuser.com/q/269818#comment1627713_269818) (2016).
- [With code page 65001, the console in all versions of Windows
  (even the new console in Windows 10) does not support non-ASCII
  input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14109024#comment79422001_18439832) (2017).
- [`chcp 65001` is very dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843552) (2017).
- [Do not use `chcp.com 65001`, except temporarily in batch
  scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131654#comment100784875_57134096) (2019).
- *Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support* [broke the
  functionality of some old and crappy programs that were working fine
  in server 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490#comment116524520_55674760) (2021).

##### Consider using MSYS2 as an alternative command-line utility

In case you desperately want a command-line tool that correctly
outputs the text of your UTF-8 encoded files, I suggest that you
download and install Linux style [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org), which by default
assumes that your text files are UTF-8 encoded.

Note that, while your UTF-8 characters are all correctly rendered :

```
$ cat Some-UTF-8-chars.txt
Sakta men säkert vinner basinkomst mark,
 och det viktigaste just nu är att hålla ihop.
```

the (non-ASCII) *ANSI* characters will instead be output as question
marks :

```
$ cat Some-ANSI-chars.txt
Sakta men s�kert vinner basinkomst mark,
 och det viktigaste just nu �r att h�lla ihop.
```

In conclusion, `cmd.exe` correctly outputs *ANSI* encoded files,
<sup>4</sup> 
while the MSYS2 terminal correctly outputs *UTF-8* encoded files.

### References

- [Post that suggests adding `"Autorun"="chcp 1252>>nul"` in the
  registry](https://superuser.com/a/1202335)
- [Code page 437 (IBM PC)](https://www.ascii-codes.com)
- [Post containing a table of ANSI encodings for ten different
  language groups](https://superuser.com/a/1744158)
- [Post explaining the difference between *encoding* in UTF-8 and
  *converting* to UTF-8](https://superuser.com/a/762475)
- [Notepad2 | download page](https://flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html)
- [Notepad++ | download page](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads)
- [Visual Studio Code | download page](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download)
- [Serious implementation bugs in Windows's code page 65001](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490#comment10782008_388500)
- [Code page 65001 is *not supported*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490#comment18817211_388500)
- [`chcp 65001` provides some UTF-8 decoding but it's very
  rudimentary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14109024#comment56860192_14109024)
- [The Windows console is riddled with bugs [for] code page
  65001](https://superuser.com/q/269818#comment1627713_269818)
- [Code page 65001 … does not support non-ASCII input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14109024#comment79422001_18439832)
- [`chcp 65001` is very dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843552)
- [Do not use `chcp.com 65001`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131654#comment100784875_57134096)
- [Beta: Unicode UTF-8 broke … some old … programs …](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490#comment116524520_55674760)
- [MSYS2 | download page](https://www.msys2.org)
- [Some-ANSI-chars.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/henk9/Henke/main/Some-ANSI-chars.txt)
- [Some-UTF-8-chars.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/henk9/Henke/main/Some-UTF-8-chars.txt)

---

<sup>1</sup>
The `.reg` file is inspired by [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1202335).
I trust that you know how to achieve the same thing *manually* in the
registry. 
It's wise to first check the registry to see if you already have a
REG_SZ value by the name `Autorun`. 
The registry hack doesn't affect PowerShell. – Open PowerShell and
run `chcp`. Expect to see `Active code page: 437`. 
Of course, I use code page 1252 in my `.bat` files as well.
About 99% of them are pure ASCII files anyway.

<sup>2</sup>
When doing this experiment, I made sure there was no `Autorun` value
under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor` in the registry.

<sup>3</sup>
To be precise, I have no less than *three* "favorite" text editors,
[Notepad2](https://flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html), [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads),
and [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download). 
Of these three, Visual Studio Code is set to encode *all* files by
UTF-8, while Notepad2 and Notepad++ 
*auto-detect* whatever encoding the editor thinks is correct.

<sup>4</sup>
Provided you've adopted the registry hack in my "short answer".