# Batch file encoding

Tags: windows, encoding, batch-file, cmd

I would like to deal with filename containing strange characters, like the French é.

Everything is working fine in the shell:

```
C:\somedir\>ren -hélice hélice
```

I know if I put this line in a .bat file, I obtain the following result:

```
C:\somedir\>ren -hÚlice hÚlice
```

See ? é have been replaced by Ú.

The same is true for command output. If I `dir` some directory in the shell, the output is fine. If I redirect this output to a file, some characters are transformed.

So how can I tell cmd.exe how to interpret what appears as an é in my batch file, is really an é and not a Ú or a comma?

So there is no way when executing a .bat file to give an hint about the codepage in which it was written?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You have to save the batch file with OEM encoding. How to do this varies depending on your text editor. The encoding used in that case varies as well. For Western cultures it's usually CP850.

Batch files and encoding are really two things that don't particularly like each other. You'll notice that Unicode is also impossible to use there, unfortunately (even though environment variables handle it fine).

Alternatively, you can set the console to use another codepage:

```
chcp 1252
```

should do the trick. At least it worked for me here.

When you do output redirection, such as with `dir`, the same rules apply. The console window's codepage is used. You can use the `/u` switch to `cmd.exe` to force Unicode output redirection, which causes the resulting files to be in UTF-16.

As for encodings and code pages in `cmd.exe` in general, also see this question:

- [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)

**EDIT:** As for your edit: No, `cmd` always assumes the batch file to be written in the console default codepage. However, you can easily include a `chcp` at the start of the batch:

```
chcp 1252>NUL
ren -hélice hélice
```

To make this more robust when used directly from the commandline, you may want to memorize the old code page and restore it afterwards:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%x in ('chcp') do set cp=%%x
chcp 1252>nul
ren -hélice hélice
chcp %cp%>nul
```

Comment: chcp works in the .bat, even if echoing is wrong. However, if I do chcp 1252 in the console, and then type test.bat, it is still wrong...

Comment: Of course it is wrong. `type` doesn't know anything about the codepage so it assumes the one you have currently set. What `chcp` in the batch does is *changing* that codepage, hence the differing results. I presented this more as a workaround anyway. The correct solution is to save the batch file in the correct encoding.

Comment: in fact, character "input" and character "output" to the screen are two different things. If I change the police of the console :
chcp 850 followed by type gives me hÛlice

chcp 1252 followed by type gives me hélice

It seems the default raster police codepage is not changed by chcp

Comment: That only barely makes sense to me. But yes, essentially the codepage set with `chcp` determines (a) how built-in commands deal with encodings and (b) what characters can and will be displayed.

Comment: Alex: For proper programming languages you should always and exclusively use Unicode. Do not ever rely on a legacy codepage on Windows if you can help it. Batch files are a sad, but notable exception where you have to.

Comment: To make a bat script that supports more generic character sets, you might want to use chcp 65001 (UTF-8) instead of chcp 1252 in your batch script. I find it ironic, however, if you save that bat file as UTF-8 with BOM, and your console is 850, the first line will cause an error message because of the weird characters at the start of the first line (ie. the BOM). But by saving the file as UTF-8 without BOM, it worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with this, and here is the solution I found. Find the decimal number for the character you are looking for in your current code page.

For example, I'm in codepage 437 (`chcp` tells you), and I want a degree sign, . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437 tells me that the degree sign is number 248.

Then you find the Unicode character with the same number.

The Unicode character at 248 (U+00F8) is .

If you insert the Unicode character in your batch script, it will display to the console as the character you desire.

So my batch file

```
echo
```

prints

```
°
```

Answer (score 1):

I created the following block, which I put at the beginning of my batch files:

```
set Filename=%0
IF "%Filename:~-8%" == "-850.bat" GOTO CONVERT_CODEPAGE_END
    rem Converting code page from 1252 to 850.
    rem My editors use 1252, my batch uses 850.
    rem We create a converted -850.bat file, and then launch it.
    set File850=%~n0-850.bat
    PowerShell.exe -Command "get-content %0 | out-file -encoding oem -filepath %File850%"
    call %File850%
    del %File850%
    EXIT /b 0
:CONVERT_CODEPAGE_END
```

Answer (score 1):

I care about three concepts:

1. Output Console Encoding
2. Command line internal encoding (that changed with chcp)
3. .bat Text Encoding

The easiest scenario to me: I will have the first two mentioned in the same encoding, say CP850, and I will store my .bat in that same encoding (in Notepad++, menu *Encoding* → *Character sets* → *Western European* → *OEM 850*).

But suppose someone hands me a .bat in another encoding, say CP1252 (in Notepad++, menu Encoding* → *Character sets* → *Western European* → *Windows-1252*)

Then I would change the command line internal encoding, with chcp 1252.

This changes the encoding it uses to talk with other processes, neither the input device nor output console.

So my command line instance will effectively send characters in 1252 through its STDOUT file descriptor, but gabbed text appears when the console decodes them out as 850 (é is Ú).

Then I modify the file as follows:

```
@echo off

perl -e "use Encode qw/encode decode/;" -e "print encode('cp850', decode('cp1252', \"ren -hlice hlice\n\"));"
ren -hlice hlice
```

First I turn echo off so the commands don't output unless explicitly doing either echo... or perl -e "print..."

Then I put this boilerplate each time I need to output something

perl -e "use Encode qw/encode decode/;" -e "print encode('cp850', decode('cp1252', \"ren -hélice hélice\n\"));"

I substitute the actual text I'll show for this:  ren -hélice hélice.

And also I could need to substitute my console encoding for cp850 and other side encoding for cp1252.

And just below I put the desired command.

I did broke the problematic line into the output half and the real command half.

- The first I make for sure: The "é" is interpreted as an "é" by means of transcoding. It is necessary for all the output sentences since the console and the file are at different encodings.
- The second, the real command (muttered with @echo off), knowing we have the same encoding both from chcp and the .bat text is enough to ensure a proper character interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

I had polish signs inside the code in R (eg. ą, ę, ź, ż etc.) and had the **problem while running this R script with .bat file** (in the output file .Rout instead of those signs there were signs like %, &, # etc. and the code didn't run to the end).

My solution:

1. **Save R script with encoding: File > Save with encoding > CP1250**
2. Run .bat file

It worked for me but if there is still the problem, try to use the other encodings.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio Code, click on the encoding at the bottom, choose `Save with encoding`, then `DOS(CP437)`.