# SVN pre-commit hook encoding

Tags: python, svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit-hook, svn-hooks

I'm using **Python** script to implement **SVN pre-commit hook**:

```
svnlookPath = 'path-to-svnlook'

f = subprocess.Popen([svnlookPath, 'log', sys.argv[1], '--transaction', sys.argv[2]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
commitMessage = f.read()
f.close()
commitMessage = commitMessage.rstrip('\n\r')

print >> sys.stderr, 'Commit message: "' + commitMessage + '"'
sys.exit(1)
```

My **pre-commit.bat** (server is hosted on Windows Server 2008):

```
@python.exe path-to-py-file %1 %2
```

On a client side I use **TortoiseSVN**.

Everything goes ok, except commit message **encoding**. If the commit message contains, for example, Russian letters they are shown as '?' (question marks) in Tortoise window.

Comment: Stop writing tags in titles please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this is more the fault of the `.bat` then of the python script, because python has excellent unicode support.
Perhaps the answer of this question can help you.

[Batch file encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427796/batch-file-encoding)

Comment: Adding 'chcp 1251' or 'chcp 65001' line in bat file doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be Tortoise itself. Try the following

svn log http://rev_url

and see what svn says the log comment is. If it gets it right, then its probably Tortoise not showing the Russian encoding. What happens if you commit without your pre-commit hook? Does that show correctly?