# How Do I COPY a file with special characters in the filename in a .BAT file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am generating a .BAT file containing nothing but COPY commands to move some files around.

Here is an example working command:

```
COPY "C:\TEST.PDF" "D:\TEST.PDF"
```

Here is an example that isn't working:

```
COPY "C:\édf.pdf" "D:\édf.pdf"
```

Can I copy this file using a windows batch file? Or do I have to rewrite my script in a language like PERL?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584423/problem-running-bat-cmd-file-with-accented-characters-in-it

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. Have you tried it?

Comment: Nevermind all, thank you. My bat file wasn't encoded properly. Those special characters were lost inside the .bat file during the file's creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples I gave do work. I noticed that inside my .BAT file those special characters were getting lost because of the .BAT file's encoding.

Comment: was there a workaround to use the special characters, or did you use regular ASCII instead?

Comment: You know, I couldn't say what the workaround was. How I was generating the .bat file was just outputting the COPY commands to the browser via a coldfusion server. I then copied those commands to a notepad and saved it. I presume it was because I saved the .bat file as ANSI format. When I saved the file using CFFILE with UTF8 encoding, it worked.