# Converting unicode characters from returned JSON in python

Tags: python, windows, json, cmd, musicbrainz

I am trying to return JSON from the API service from musicbrainz, the returned data for some songs have unicode characters which I am having trouble converting them to regular symbols etc. Kindly let me know what I should be doing here.

JSON:

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "results": [{
        "recordings": [{
            "duration": 402,
            "tracks": [{
                "duration": 402,
                "position": 6,
                "medium": {
                    "release": {
                        "id": "dde6ecee-8e9b-4b46-8c28-0f8d659f83ac",
                        "title": "Tecno Fes, Volume 2"
                    },
                    "position": 1,
                    "track_count": 11
                },
                "artists": [{
                    "id": "57c1e5ea-e08f-413a-bcb1-f4e4b675bead",
                    "name": "Gigi D\u2019Agostino"
                }],
                "title": "You Spin Me Round"
            }],
            "id": "2e0a7bce-9e44-4a63-a789-e8c4d2a12af9"
        }, ....
```

Failed Code (example):

```
string = '\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f'
print string.encode('utf-8')
```

I am using this on a windows 7 machine and have python 2.7 and running this code on a command line terminal.. I have the output I get below:

```
C:\Python27>python junk.py Gigi DGÇÖAgostino Gigi D?Agostino Gigi D\u2019Agostino
```

I am expecting the output to be `Gigi D' Agostino`

Comment: What is a "normal" character?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is here.  I ran the JSON you gave through the standard JSON decoder and the one bit of non-ASCII came out correctly as "Gigi D’Agostino".  The "Failed Code", you're just missing a character.  If you write `string = u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f'`, the variable is properly set to `Россия`.  BTW, don't use "string" as a variable name; it can only end in tears.

Comment: Do you mean you need ASCII encoded strings?  Why?  What are you actually doing with this data?

Comment: I am trying to get some metadata that eventually will be used to manage media, hence the need to encode it properly. the desired output is "Gigi D’Agostino" while all tried codes and methods dont address this issue...
<br>
 `print u'Gigi D\u2019Agostino'.encode('utf-8')`'
<br>
 `print u'Gigi D\u2019Agostino'.encode('iso-8859-15', 'replace')`
<br>
 `a = u'Gigi D\u2019Agostino'
 import re
 a = re.sub(r'[\x80-\xFF]+', lambda x: x.group(0).encode('latin1').decode('utf8'), a)
 print a.encode('utf8')`

Comment: didn't you forget to specify encoding in script? `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Tried all the below methods but none succeded...  

 `# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-`  

 `print u'Gigi D\u2019Agostino'.encode('utf-8')`  
 `print u'Gigi D\u2019Agostino'.encode('iso-8859-15', 'replace')`  
  
 `out = 'Gigi D\u2019Agostino'
 out = out.replace( u'\u2018', u"'")
 out = out.replace( u'\u2019', u"'")
 out = out.replace( u'\u201c', u'"')
 out = out.replace( u'\u201d', u'"')
 out.encode('ascii')
 print out`
  
  
 `a = u'Gigi D\u2019Agostino'
 import re
 a = re.sub(r'[\x80-\xFF]+', lambda x: x.group(0).encode('latin1').decode('utf8'), a)
 print a.encode('utf8')`

Comment: How did they "not succeed"?  Did they print anything?  Did they raise exceptions?  What output do you expect?  What platform are you running this on?  Are you running this on the terminal/command line, IDLE, Eclipse, something else?

Comment: I am using this on a windows 7 machine and have python 2.7 and running this code on a command line terminal.. I have the output I get below:  

C:\Python27>python junk.py
Gigi DGÇÖAgostino
Gigi D?Agostino
Gigi D\u2019Agostino

Comment: I am expecting the output to be --Gigi D' Agostino--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `cmd` in Windows? In that case it might be a bit of a hack to get Unicode working at all to display correctly.
You might want to think about using another "terminal" to test your scripts.
[MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/) provides a nice terminal/shell and IDLE is included in the Windows Python distribution and has a Python Shell (right click, open in IDLE, F5).

If you really want to make it work in the `cmd`:

You have to set `Lucida Console` as font in `cmd`. Then:

```
> chcp
Active code page: 850
> chcp 65001
```

Then you should have unicode output in the `cmd`. Your "Active code page" might be different. Note that somewhere, because you might want to change it back afterwards:

```
> chcp 850
```

Otherwise you will run into other problems (starting `.bat` files doesn't work).
(See also [batch-file-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427796/batch-file-encoding))

In your script you also need this:

```
import codecs

def cp65001(name):
    """This might be buggy, but better than just a LookupError
    """
    if name.lower() == "cp65001":
        return codecs.lookup("utf-8")

codecs.register(cp65001)
```

Otherwise python will crash. (see [windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878972/windows-cmd-encoding-change-causes-python-crash))

I had a similar [bug report](https://github.com/JonnyJD/musicbrainz-isrcsubmit/issues/40) for my script.

---

You might also consider using a library to access the MusicBrainz Web Service.
[Python-musicbrainzngs](http://python-musicbrainzngs.readthedocs.org/) works with the current ws/2.

Comment: Nice article, but I don't get the connection to this answer, other than also being about unicode in Python.

Comment: I get LookupError: unknown encoding: cp65001

Comment: Looks like you forgot the `codecs.register(cp65001)` part. I also added `import codecs` in the example to make it clear where `codecs` comes from.

Answer (score 1):

*Unicode escape only works with unicode strings, to convert your regular string to unicode use `str.decode('unicode-escape')`:*

```
In [1]: s='\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f'

In [2]: s
Out[2]: '\\u0420\\u043e\\u0441\\u0441\\u0438\\u044f'

In [3]: s.decode('unicode-escape')
Out[3]: u'\u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f'

In [4]: print s.decode('unicode-escape')
Россия

In [5]: s2="Gigi D\u2019Agostino"

In [6]: s2
Out[6]: 'Gigi D\\u2019Agostino'

In [7]: print s2.decode('unicode-escape')
Gigi D’Agostino
```

Comment: Wonder if this has anything to do with my commandline terminial now:

Comment: `s2 = 'Gigi D\\u2019Agostino'
print s2.decode('unicode-escape')`
<p>
<br>

<br/>
`C:\Python27>python junk.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "junk.py", line 2, in <module>
    print s2.decode('unicode-escape')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 6: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @PremMinister -- how are you running this? if you copy paste it to a interactive python interpreter does it work?

Comment: `.decode('unicode-escape')` shouldn't be necessary for a json-text.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- You are of course right. I was for some reason assuming, that for some reason the problem presisted after using a parser, because "how else would he have gotten the string extracted?"...

Comment: >>> s = "some\x00string. with\x15 funny characters"
>>> import string
>>> filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, s)
'somestring. with funny characters'

Answer (score 0):

You should use json parser that returns Unicode string as any valid json parser does. Your failing example shows a bytestring i.e., you haven't used a json parser.

For example, to parse json data:

```
obj = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))
```

To pretty print `obj` without using Unicode escapes:

```
print json.dumps(obj, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
```

It is also useful to understand the difference between:

```
print unicode_string
```

And:

```
print repr(unicode_string)
```