# How to -draw text with special character -like ë- in ImageMagick

Tags: text, imagemagick, special-characters, draw

I would like to draw some special characters on my image, but the letter **ë** in Azië is represented with wrong coded characters.
actually i wrote my script on a *.bat UTF8 encoded file.
Is there a way to solve it?

this is my example code:

```
-draw "rotate -4 text 385,335 'Azië'"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using latin1 encoding?

Comment: still not working, it prints another letter (basically this Ù)

Comment: Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427796/batch-file-encoding

It's definitely an encoding problem

Answer (score 0):

after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427796/batch-file-encoding)  - you may save the batch file in Windows 1252 encoding (or another), then wrap your commands in this lines:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%x in ('chcp') do set cp=%%x

rem here you change the codepage (encoding)
chcp 1252>nul

rem your commands here
-draw "rotate -4 text 385,335 'Azië'"

chcp %cp%>nul
```