# French symbols aren't displayed in console Windows

Tags: java, maven, cmd, maven-3, pom.xml

In my java console application the french symbols aren't displayed, I can see just a '?'.
I've tried 'chcp 65001' but it doesn't work. I build my project with Maven 3. In Debian 9's console everything works fine. But in Windows's cmd.exe end GitBashForWin nothing works.

POM.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: Have you tried `chcp 1252`?

Comment: See the questions [Batch file encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427796/), [CMD can't read Danish characters when I execute .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046559/) and [Using another language (code page) in a batch file made for others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981387/). Windows console is by default not designed for UTF-8 encoded text like Linux terminals. I don't know if Java has a function to get OEM code page as set for current user according to user's country configuration to convert the strings to this code page before output on console.

Comment: Thank you, the command `chcp 1252` works fine, the french symbols are displayed.