# Replace string with unicode in text file via Windows batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, unicode, find-replace

I have a file with this simple contents:

**test.txt** (ASCII encoded)

`Baby, you can drive my :car:`

Via a Windows batch file, I need to change `:car:` to   (https://unicode-table.com/en/1F697/)

I'd like to avoid installing new software on the client's server, so I'm trying to do it using PowerShell or something native.

So far I've tried a ton of suggestions (https://www.generacodice.com/en/articolo/30745/How-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-Windows-command-line-environment?), but nothing works for me.  Either it doesn't get replaced, or \u1F697 shows up literally.  I've tried changing the inbound file's encoding to Unicode and that isn't working either.

Non-working example:

`powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace ':car:', '' | Out-File -encoding Unicode test.txt"`

Does anyone have any tips?

Edit: I've determined how to reproduce it.

If I run this line via command line, it works:

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace ':car:', '' | Out-File -encoding utf8 test-out.txt"
```

If I put the same line of code inside `replace.bat` and then execute it, test-out.txt is corrupt.

The batch file is set to UTF-8 encoding.  Should something be different?

Comment: "Either it doesn't get replaced, or \u1F697 shows up literally" - which one is it, with the "non-working" example?

Comment: I retested the code to answer your question and magically it worked on my laptop.  `:car:` is replaced with the car emoji.  But on the client's server, the same command replaces the client's file with `ƒÜù`.

Comment: I assume that `ƒÜù` is due to an interpreter reading the file with a different encoding than the file actually is

Comment: That's a good call.  I'll have to take a look at what they are using and what the encoding seems to be.

Comment: I did more debugging and found a clear way to reproduce it.  I've edited my post with the details.  @NicoNekoru

Comment: `-replace ':car:', [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F697)` (as Windows `.bat` script interpreter does not understand neither `utf-8` nor `utf-16`).

Comment: Like @JosefZ said, the interpreter for batch interprets not as UTF but as Unicode. Most of the time this is ok since unicode and utf-8 both use ASCII for single bytes. In this case since the car is a 4 byte character in both Unicode and UTF-8 there are differences

Comment: @JosefZ You're answer was correct + first, so I'd like to give you credit for it.  If you want to post it as an answer, I'll flag it as the winner.  Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows `.bat` script interpreter does not understand any Unicode encoding (e.g. `utf-8` or `utf-16` or `utf-16`); the simplest principle is:

> [You have to save the batch file with `OEM` encoding. How to do this
> varies depending on your text editor. The encoding used in that case
> varies as well. For Western cultures it's usually `CP850`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1427817/3439404)

To use any Unicode character (above ASCII range) as a part of string passed to PowerShell command then (instead of `''`) apply the [.NET method `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.convertfromutf32?view=net-5.0); in terms of PowerShell syntax `[char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F697)`

Being in ASCII it does not contradicts with above `.bat` encoding rule, and PowerShell would evaluate it to the  character…

Then, your line could be as follows:

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt) -replace ':car:', [char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F697) | Out-File -encoding Unicode test.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a .bat file can have non-ascii encoding.  If you're willing to have a file.ps1 file:

```
(gc test.txt) -replace ':car:', '' | Out-File -encoding utf8 test-out.txt
```

The file has to be saved as utf8 with bom in notepad, not just utf8.

Then your .bat file would be:

```
powershell -file file.ps1
```

The powershell ise is a nice way to test this.

```
cmd /c file.bat
type test-out.txt
```

Comment: This was helpful as well!  Thanks for posting.