# Convert string from codepage 1252 to 1250

Tags: java, codepages, cp1252, cp1250

How can I convert one `String` with characters decoded in codepage 1252 into a `String` decoded in codepage 1250.

For example

```
String str1252 = "ê¹ś¿źæñ³ó";
String str1250 = convert(str1252);
System.out.print(str1250);
```

I want to find such `convert()` function, that printed output would be:

```
ęąśżźćńłó
```

These are Polish-specific characters.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the context of this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward:

```
public String convert(String s) {
    return new String(s.getBytes("Windows-1252"), "Windows-1250");
}
```

Note that `System.out.print()` can introduce [another incorrect conversion due to mismatch between ANSI and OEM code pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747358/java-unicode-confusion/4747502). However `System.console().writer().print()` should output it correctly.

Comment: It breaks 'ś' and 'ź' for some reason, though. Maybe because they aren't in the Windows-1250? Not sure as I haven't used any of these encodings.

Comment: @Sergey: Yes, these characters are absent in [Windows-1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It almost works. If the character is > 256 then it wont be converted to bytes properly (it's changed to 63 - '?'). Therefore the additional detection is required for every char of the String. I have found the below code working: 

bytes[] bytes = text.getBytes("Windows-1252");
String text1250 = new String(bytes, "Windows-1250");
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(text1250);

for (int i = 0 ; i < bytes.length ; i ++){
  chars[i] = text.charAt(i);
  if (chars[i] > 256)
    buffer.replace(i, i+1, text.substring(i, i+1));
}
text1250 = buffer.toString();

Comment: @rybz, I'd change that to `if (buffer.charAt(i) == '?' && text.charAt(i) != '?')` - that is, if it wasn't '?' but became '?', then take the original char instead. This has the advantage of working correctly even if some chars that aren't > 256 turn out to be broken too.

Comment: @Sergey, that might be a good point. I haven't found a case of a character <= 256 that would be converted improperly. You also have to make sure, that a char that is <= 256 and converts broken, is a valid type for the target codepage - I haven't checked that solution, but it might be advantageous.