# German characters in Java

Tags: java, diacritics

I want to set german words (with special characters) into String var.

```
String s = "Staatsangehörigkeit";
System.out.println(s);
```

but in output or in debuger I see: Staatsangeh?rigkeit.

Comment: Maybe your output's font doesn't contain this character?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display special characters using System.out.println](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10933620/display-special-characters-using-system-out-println)

Comment: To get correct results you can use System.console().writer().println() instead.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4747502/3651739

Comment: I have tried running the same but i am getting the correct output, maybe as mentioned above you won't be having font support for German.

Comment: That can be the case, if the console is say for the Greek encoding. Then `ö` cannot be represented.

Comment: You can use Locale for this Check the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/create.html.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to change the encoding of your project to **UTF-8**.

When using eclipse:

1. Right-Click on your project folder
2. Properties
3. Resource
4. Then change the text-file encoding

Answer (score 0):

The '?' is caused by "umlaute" `ä = ae`, `ü = ue`, `ö = oe`.