# C# WinForms Process Encoding problem

Tags: c#, winforms, encoding, utf-8, process

I am writing a windows forms application in C#
I have a Process Object which runs a cmd command and returns it's output.

```
Process Pro = new Process();
Pro.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
Pro.StartInfo.Arguments = "<Dos Command here>";
Pro.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
Pro.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
Pro.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
Pro.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Pro.Start();
```

Which works fine! However if the output of the command is not ASCII(in my case Greek), the Output are random symbols. Surely an encoding problem.
If i run the same code on a console application everything runs smoothly.

I tried reading the Base stream as UTF-8, but no luck!

```
System.IO.StreamReader Rdr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Pro.StandardOutput.BaseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Is there any way to read the output properly in a winform application?
Thnx!

Comment: Perhaps [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using) can help?

Comment: Assign the StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding property.  To what encoding is unguessable.  Maybe 737, the old DOS code page for Greek.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is base on this:
[unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)
check here:
[Wiki code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)
for the code page you need.

you can also do an ugly hack, writing the command to a batch file (f.e foo.bat)
then running it as `foo.bat > log.txt`
then you can read the output from log.txt.