# How to read non-ASCII characters from CLI standard input

Tags: php, character-encoding, stdin, fgets

If I type `å` in CMD, fgets stop waiting for more input and the loop runs until I press `ctrl-c`. If I type a "normal" characters like a-z0-9!?() it works as expected.

I run the code in CMD under Windows 7 with UTF-8 as charset (`chcp 65001`), the file is saved as UTF-8 without bom. I use PHP 5.3.5 (cli).

```
<?php

echo "ÅÄÖåäö work here.\n";

while(1)
{
    echo '> '. fgets(STDIN);
}

?>
```

If I change charset to `chcp 1252` the loop doesn't break when I type `å` and it print "> å" but the "ÅÄÖåäö work here" become "Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶ work here!". And I know that I can change the file to ANSI, but then I can't use special characters like ╠╦╗.

**So why does fgets stop waiting for userinput after I have typed åäö?**

**And how can I fix this?**

EDIT:

Also found a strange bug.
`echo "öäåÅÄÖåäö work here! Or?".chr(10);` -> `��äåÅÄÖåäö work here! Or? re! Or?`.
If the first char in echo is `å/ä/ö` it print strange chars AND the end output duplicate's with `n - 1` char.. (n = number of åäö in the begining of the string).

Eg: `echo "åäö 1234" -> ??äö 123434` and `echo åäöåäö 1234` -> `??äöåäö 1234 1234`.

**EDIT2 (solved):**

The problem was `chcp 65001`, now I use `chcp 437` ([chcp 437](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305156)).
Big thanks to Timothy Martens!

Comment: A few questions about this problem: 1) what happens when you try to type and `å` in the CMD outside of the php? 2) It is only logical that an UTF-8 `Å` is not the same as an windows-1252 `Å` thus the resulting `Ã`. But what happens if you try to convert the PHP file into windows-1252?

Comment: **1)** åäö -> "command not fond", echo åäö -> åäö. So it works. Both with `chcp 65001` (UTF-8) and `chcp 1252`. **2)** I use UTF-8 in cmd AND as charset for the PHP file. If I use windows-1252 in the PHP file nothing changes. I think the problem is in windows/PHP. When I use `chcp 1252` it work for ÅÄÖ (even if the PHP file is UTF-8), but    then I can't use ╠╦╗ etc.

Comment: Man, what an interesting question ^^. You really have my attention now. I'm going to experiment myself for a bit, and I'll tell you as soon as I find anything.

Comment: I wonder... what if you would use fgetsc(STDIN)? Probably the same, but it might produce another(unwanted? :P) result...

Comment: @Qqwy `var_dump(fgetc(STDIN))` -> bool(false); `var_dump(fgets(STDIN))` -> bool(false); when I type `å` (or äö). Else it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
echo '>'; 
$line = stream_get_line(STDIN, 999999, PHP_EOL);
```

Notes:
I was unable to reproduce your error using multiple versions of PHP.
Using the following PHP version 5.3.8 gave me no issues

> PHP 5.3 (5.3.8)
>   VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe (2011-Aug-23 12:26:18)
>   Arcitechture is Win XP SP3 32 bit

You might try upgrading PHP.

I downloaded php-5.3.5-nts-Win32-VC6-x86 and was not able to reproduce your error, it works fine for me.

Edit: Additionaly I typed the characters using my spanish keyboard.

Edit2:

CMD Command:

```
chcp 437
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$fp=fopen("php://stdin","r");
while(1){
    $str =  fgets(STDIN);
    echo mb_detect_encoding($str)."\n";
    echo '>'.stream_get_line($fp,999999,"\n")."\n";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
test
ASCII
test
>test
öïü

öïü
>öïü
```

Comment: **1)** `stream_get_line` didn't work. **2)** I downloaded `VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe (2011-Aug-23 12:26:18)` now, but it didn't work. What charset did you use in CMD and in your code? Btw I run W7 64bit.

Comment: @Timoth Martens On windows cmd wouldn't it be `stream_get_line(STDIN, 999999, PHP_EOL);`? I updated your answer anyhow. +1 anyway. seems like the best solution so far.

Comment: **NOTE**: I just tested this on my Mac using PHP 5.3.6 and PHP 5.2.14 and both worked.

Comment: @mmmshuddup Sadly it don't work for me :( Can you post your code and your charset (both console and code charset)? Because I have tested with `ansi/utf8 utf8/utf8 utf8/ansi` with all solutions posted here I think.. no of them work for me.

Comment: @Sawny I'm using in cmd "Active code page: 437" You can change yours by running "chcp 437" in cmd.

Comment: I'm curious as to what yours is??? You can detect it by just running the command in cmd "chcp".

I found this question in on chcp if you want more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: @Sawny Curiously when I type normal letters php reports it detects ANSI but when I type the special chars PHP reports nothing. I'm using mb_detect_encoding() to tell me what the encoding is.

Answer (score 2):

I think that happens because PHP 5.3 does not support properly multibyte characters.

These chars: `ÅÄÖåäö`

Are binary: `c3 85 c3 84 c3 96 c3 a5 c3 a4 c3 b6` (without BOM at beggining)

Citing [PHP String](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> A string is series of characters, where a character is the same as a byte. This means that PHP only supports a 256-character set, and hence does not offer native Unicode support. See details of the string type.

Normally does not affect the final result, because the browser/reader understand multibyte characters, but for CMD and STDIN buffer is `Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶` (12 chars/bytes char array).

only [MB functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) handle multibyte strings basic operations.

Comment: Yes I know about the MB functions, but they doesn't have any read resource function :(