# php stdin input return blank value with arabic chars

Tags: php, powershell, encoding, command-line-interface, charset

i'm makin my own php cli but i need to use **arabic letters**
so fgets return blank value from command line input
Knowing i'm using powershell to run commands

```php
function input(string $prompt = null) {
   echo "$prompt\r\n";
   $handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
   $output = fgets ($handle);
   return trim ($output);
}
var_dump(input("Enter Arabic Word: "));
```

**terminal preview :**

> > php cli.php 
> < Enter Arabic Word: 
> > علي
> < ""

Comment: Looks PowerShell specific. Testing that with WSL2 Ubuntu22 works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read non-ASCII characters from CLI standard input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331353/how-to-read-non-ascii-characters-from-cli-standard-input)