# PHP urlencode charset encoding issue

Tags: php, character-encoding, urlencode

I got this php script:

```
$str = "ú";
echo $str . ' -> ' . urlencode($str) . "\n" ;
```

**Expected Result:**

```
ú -> %FA
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

**Actual Result**

```
ú -> %C3%BA
```

Comment: What is your issue? You think the example is lying?

Comment: [Don't trust anything w3schools tells you](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: I expect thar urlencode('ú') returns %FA instead of %C3%BA

Comment: What char set is that letter in? As well, [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: @texai: It does, but not for every `ú` - computers differ how any character is represented, depending on the charset encoding. For LATIN-1 it does (`%FA`), for UTF-8 it does not (`%C3%BA`).

Comment: @hakre: What is the correct way to make my example script returns my expected result ?

Comment: As an aside, what encoding does Windows cmd.exe use such that the above script would give me `%A3` instead?

Comment: @texai: That highly depends on the charset encoding you want to use for `$str`. I would say, if you don't have any specific needs, go with UTF-8. But also see: [Handling character encodings in HTML and CSS](http://www.w3.org/International/tutorials/tutorial-char-enc/) and [Character encodings for beginners](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding).

Comment: @Wiseguy: Please see [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using). But to get `%A3` you need to change the charset encoding of the PHP file (not of the shell, or at least not at first).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
urlencode(utf8_decode($str));
```

That should give you the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You encode the `ú` as UTF-8 (check the encoding of your example code), so `urlencode` does correctly encode it as `%C3%BA`.

You were more or less referring to this:

```
$str = "\xFA"; # ú in LATIN-1
echo $str . ' -> ' . urlencode($str) . "\n" ;
```

Which gives you your expected result, regardless how you encode the php-code/-file:

```
ú -> %FA
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/6xUT4x), that site is using UTF-8 to store the source-code. If you want the output displayed as LATIN-1, this [additional example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5gOVq7) signals the browser the LATIN-1 charset:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=latin-1');
$str = "\xFA"; # ú in LATIN-1
echo $str . ' -> ' . urlencode($str) . "\n" ;
```