# Incorrect encoding after redirecting `dir` output to a file

Tags: encoding, batch-file, cmd

I run this code on Windows cmd.exe in Europe and I use local settings here, for my language. So I use diacritics in names of the directories.

I try to list names of the directories and they are displayed correctly. Then I save them into file, but when I open it in notepad, the diacritics is not readable: for example, instead of `Střední Čechy` I have `Stýednˇ ¬echy`.

What did I do wrong and how can I correct it?

```
@echo off
del directories.conf
FOR /F "delims=!" %%R IN ('dir * /b /a:d /o:n') DO (

 IF EXIST "%%R\scenery" ( 
  echo %%R
  echo %%R >> directories.conf
 ) ELSE (ECHO NOT INCLUDED %%R)

)
Echo Directory list created...
pause
```

Comment: Is this Windows XP or Vista+?

Comment: Please, don't put two separate issues in one question, especially if answers have been already posted. This makes both question and answer less usable in future. I suggest you 1. revert the last edit 2. try to find answer to reading issue, 3. if not found, open new question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try starting cmd.exe with /u switch.  That will cause cmd to write in UTF-16.

Also you need to switch to code page 1250 (ANSI for Central Europe) using `chcp 1250`.

You can do it inside your batch script. I made one for you. The structure is:

```
.\Jižní Morava
.\Jižní Morava\scenery
.\Pelhřimov
.\Pelhřimov\scenery
.\Nic moc výlet
.\Střední Čechy
.\Střední Čechy\scenery
```

And the script:

```
@echo off

if _%1_==_main_ (
    call :main
) else (
    cmd /u /c "%0 main"
)
goto :eof

:main
    chcp 1250
    del directories.conf
    for /F "delims=!" %%R in ('dir * /b /a:d /o:n') do (
        if exist %%R\scenery (
            echo %%R
            echo %%R >> directories.conf
        ) else (
            echo not included: %%R
        )
    )
    echo Directory list created...
    pause
goto :eof
```

Also I recommend you to read [andrewdotn's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177904/835945) to a related question.

Comment: Created and tested on Windows 7

Comment: Oh thanks. I read the post you refer me. I have CP 852. Then I used almost the same script as you post, but I used CP 852. No change to me. If I woould change CP to 850 so no directories will be found because no such directories exist (different characters would be used). So I could try to set the CP before echo filenamex >> output_filename and than set the CP back. But in this case also nothing happens. I also tried ^>^> but no file was created. I cannot use cmd console, it is batch-file as installation file for users. PS: Do you understand my language?

Comment: For me it works both with 852 and 1250.  My language in Windows is set to English, though I also have Czech installed.  However, I edited the batch so that it will heat up itself in Unicode mode right away. Maybe it could help you (at least it avoids quoting issues).

Comment: P.S.: and yes, I do understand Czech--I'm a native, living in Brno. However, it's OT here--this is strictly English-only site :)

Comment: AAAH 1250! Yeah this works! Thanks. So I was so surprised, when you offered similar directory structure which I have in my PC, including Pelhřimov :-) Thanks for help.

Comment: I edited the question, because I would also like to read the file back (list the files written in the .conf file). But it results in incorrect charset even if I use cp1250 or cp852.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution (if the file is already generated) you can just **re-encode** your file.

[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) has this feature:

- Go to *Encoding > Character sets*
- Select the appropriate character set that has a graceful render
- Go back to *Encoding > Character sets*
- Select *Convert to UTF-8*
- Save your file