# Issue with coding Windows-1250 in Perl

Tags: perl, encoding

I have a text file encoded in Windows-1250. I'm using Windows 7 EN.

I would like to iterate through this file line by line in Perl code with
print.  In console I cannot see the diacritic signs.

Could you give me any solution?

Comment: Please post your code so far. What do you see instead of the expected characters? Don't forget your terminal (or Windows' `cmd.exe`) will make an interpretation of the encoding too - it is possible to have everything correct in code but still not see what you want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are going to do with the text, but for many cases
it's possible to code independently on encoding.  Anyway, if you redirect
output to a file and the result is OK (read: can be displayed opened by
text editor in Windows 1250 mode using proper font), your code is not the
problem.

The other thing is that you want to see CE characters in your console.
For that to work you need to do:

- set your console window to use font capable of displaying them (you
  may need to install such font, I don't remember The Right Way in Win 7)
- set your console to Windows-1250 mode using command `chcp 1250`

Note that this is basically the same you would need to do with your viewer
or editor to see the characters.  Except that while many editors are able
to detect encoding themselves (sometimes even correctly) and pick the right
font, consoles typically need help from you.

Your problem might be similar to what [has been solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905740/incorrect-encoding-after-redirecting-dir-output-to-a-file/9906184#9906184).  I also
recommend reading [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using) I'm referencing there.