# Why won't my console display the copyright symbol ©?

Tags: windows-8, command-line, encoding, c#

I am trying to write a C# console application the displays the copyright symbol ©. According to [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644785/is-it-possible-to-get-a-copyright-symbol-in-c-sharp-console-application) that should be possible. However, on my Windows 8 console display I get the lowercase letter c printed out. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: What do you mean? My PC? Well I can type and read the © character in a web browser, text editor, etc. So I guess the answer is yes.

Comment: The program/Visual Studio.

Comment: C# stores strings in UTF-16. According to the link I references, this should work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Huh. This repros on my copy of Windows 8 Enterprise RTM. Steps: 1) stick the code in his linked answer to blah.cs, 2) run csc blah.cs 3) run blah.exe. 4) Try changing the fonts around - still repros. Presumably the console doesn't support extended characters? This is en-us, no langpacks installed etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution. Add this before your Console.WriteLine commands:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

That same sample you linked to works if I do that.

Credit for the solution: [How to make console be able to print any of 65535 UNICODE characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721907/how-to-make-console-be-able-to-print-any-of-65535-unicode-characters)

Marking this as community wiki since I'm not really the one who knew the answer.

Comment: That worked. I did have to change my font in the console from the default raster fonts to something else, but it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. Interesting to know about the fonts - I had mine set to Lucida Console or something so that might be why it just worked for me.

Comment: @Sathya Not only that, it migrated my previous comment which I made on Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a custom font for your console? If so, that font may not have support for the (c) character.

Comment: No. Everything is vanilla.

Comment: Well I tested on 2 separate computers and both fail to display the ©, so I now think the problem is in Visual Studio. I'm going to ask this on StackOverflow.