# Ruby display unicode character

Tags: ruby, eclipse, unicode

I'm trying to print out some Unicode characters:

```
# encoding: utf-8
puts "ử ậ ắ ặ ố ồ"
```

If I run it through Powershell, this is what I get:

[image]

If I run it through cmd, this is what I get:

[image]

If I run it in Eclipse (with Aptana Studio 3 plugin), this is what I get:

[image]

Is it a problem with my system/software or is it Ruby's problem? How can I get it to work?

It works on Ideone though: http://ideone.com/PdycKH

Comment: what about running it in cmd?

Comment: It is probably a problem with cmd. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: For me it seem that this is problem with system/software. According to my knowledge Windows console doesn't work properly with UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

- For `cmd` and `Powershell`, I have to change the font (I changed to Consolas)
- In Eclipse, I have to change the encoding: go to Run/Run configurations, select the Common tab, change the `Encoding` to `Other: UTF-8`

Answer (score 4):

Ruby supports it no problem, and setting the formatting at the top of the file is the way to go.

The issue is the display via the command line window. You need to use both a font and character page that supports Unicode display.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how) regarding doing this in the Windows command line.

[About the chcp command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/chcp.mspx?mfr=true)