# Batch unicode support?

Tags: batch-file

How do I add unicode support in my batch file? I tried saving it as unicode and utf-8 but it still doesn't display foreign text properly.
Example file:

```
@echo off
echo привет
pause
```

Comment: Are you unable to save your Unicode batch file, or are you unable to run it?

Comment: When I try to run it, it opens for a split second and closes automatically even though I added a pause at the end

Comment: If you launch it from a command prompt, it won't close, and you'll be able to see what went wrong.

Comment: _'l@' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file._ The l at the beginning is actually a bar and the error is referring to the first line in my batch file, `@echo off`

Comment: Please update your question with a sample of your code, including the line containing `l@`.

Comment: alright, added an example

Comment: [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)

Comment: the problem you have may be related to [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) being present in your file (which will trip cmd interpreter). Look for 'save utf-8 without BOM' or similar in your editor.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_pages_on_Microsoft_Windows)

> The active OEM code page can be changed by the MS-DOS chcp command,
>   but this will not display correctly unless you switch from the default
>   raster font to Lucida Console. Raster fonts do not support
>   non-system-wide changing of the code page.

If your batch file is in UTF-8, try executing `chcp 65001` before your batch file  (65001=CP_UTF8) and change font to Lucida Console.

Comment: I tried using that and saved a second batch file with foreign characters in it as Unicode but it still doesn't work

Comment: This is what I get when I add `chcp 65001` as the first line in my batch file: [link](http://i.imgur.com/4WmqKQc.png)