# How to rename files with 'em' dash

Tags: batch-file, rename

I've got a batch file that I use to rename all files in a particular folder.  After renaming, there are characters that I don't recognize.  It's supposed to rename

whatever `file name.jpg` to `new file name - something.jpg`

But in place of the long dash, there is a some strange character that looks like a `U` with a caret over it.  Similar problem with the apostrophe.  In place of the apostrophe, it looks like there's a character `AE` mashed up together.  See screenshot for reference

[image: screenshot]

Here's a sample of my batch file

```
cd /
@echo
T:
ren "T:\Photos\19292955_somefilename1.jpg" "Casting – November Crew.jpg.jpg"
ren "T:\Photos\19293030_somefilename2.jpg" "Casting – October Crew.jpg.jpg"
ren "T:\Photos\19290568_somefilename3.jpg" "Nov – O'Reilley.jpg""
```

Comment: Can you try to save your batch file in ANSI (in notepad you can choose that on the file save as dialog)

Comment: you can't have long names in DOS, let alone names with spaces or dash. It's not Windows

Answer (score 0):

Would adding this to the title help? `chcp 65001`

Sources:

1. [Using non-ASCII characters in a cmd batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813495/using-non-ascii-characters-in-cmd-batch-file)
2. [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)

Answer (score 0):

Use an editor such as [EDITPLUS](http://www.editplus.com/) or NOTEPAD++, not a word-processor or even standard Notepad to edit batch files. Word-processors and WP-wannabes try to format the code by using control-codes.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still can't operate folders and files with long dash (em-dash) in the full path:

1. At first use ANSI (Windows) code page in your .bat file. Not OEM (DOS) because there is no such symbol in OEM-coding table. I prefer SynWrite text editor for this purpose.
2. Before you address to string, or before you get a string of the path containing em-dash in .bat file change code page to your local windows page (1251 fo Russia) using `chcp` operator.
3. After you finish operating a string of the path containing em-dash change code page back to 866

Code for example:

```
chcp 1251
RENAME "c:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2013 — Русский\R19.0\rus\Plotters\Plot1" Plot2
chcp 866
@pause
```

Comment: phuclv, thank's for your comment. I'm not very good in English