# How to read UTF-8 text file in Groovy?

Tags: file, encoding, utf-8, groovy

I have UTF-8 file and I want to print its content, so I tried:

```
println new File("C://Problem_1.txt").getText("UTF-8")
```

But the result is:

```
я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜ я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜я┐╜
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you ensure the text you saved is in UTF-8 and correct?

Comment: Could you please first the encoding is utf8? println new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("C://Problem_1.txt"))).encoding

Comment: I do what mr Garcia said and the output is UTF8. I open the file with Notepad++ and change the encoding to UTF-8 and then UTF-8 without BOM but nothing happens. The UFT-8 character are not shown properly

Comment: Does your output display support UTF-8? If you're using Windows command prompt, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: OK in the matter of fact I don't want to print it, I want to use this value in I method. I don't see UTF-8 on console I wrote chcp 1252. But again nothing. I want to use the file content in
ByteArrayOutputStream out = QRCode.from(it.getText("utf-8"))
                    .to(ImageType.PNG).withCharset("utf-8").stream();

Where "it" is the file. If the console is broken Ok. But why can't pass it on the method? If I pass UTF-8 literals every thing is OK the problem is when read from the file.

Comment: Dont use unicode with images/bin files, you should use base64 encoding