# Read UTF8 file with std and print strings to console

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, utf-8, std

I'm so confused it is not funny.

Using VS2012, console project, the character set in the configuration is set to unicode.

The file is in UTF8.

I'm loading it with `std::ifstream` into a vector of `std::string`. The BOM is also taken care of and the bytes shown in the debugger match those in the file.

How on earth do I print this string to the console?

This line `printf( "%s\n", line.c_str() );` only prints garbage.

Nothing special. Here is the complete code:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream file( fullpath );

if( file == NULL )
{
    printf( "Error opening file\n" );

    return;
}

file.seekg( 3, file.beg );

while( std::getline( file, line ) )
{
    printf( "%s\n", line.c_str() );
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `printf` instead of `cout`?  Anyhow, nothing is wrong with that line, can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: And the terminal you're printing to can handle UTF8?

Comment: I'm using the Windows console. Why wouldn't it be able to print utf8?

Comment: @Namfuak cout also prints garbage, the exact same garbage actually.

Comment: @Lara, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/388500/1535706

Comment: See [this old question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using).

Comment: This horse has already been beaten to death. Try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=display+unicode+windows+console+stackoverflow).

Comment: Ok, ok. So what you guys are saying is that the problem is the console. If I were to run the same code on a windows application, there would be no problem. Is this correct?

Comment: "Is this correct?" You will have to convert UTF8 to the native Windows encoding which is UTF16 (or is it UCS2? Never sure with Windows), and use native wide-character Windows APIs.