# PHP, regex issue with non Latin characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, non-latin

In a string I'm trying to remove everything inside parentheses with preg_replace but I have some issue with non Latin characters.
I tried:

```
$text = '(Hàng Refurbished) sdfsdfsdfsd (Đen)';
$text = preg_replace('#\([A-Z0-9p{L}]+\)#i', '', $text);
$text = preg_replace('# $#','', $text);
echo $text;
```

but it's not working

Any suggestion please?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: if everything is to be removed why cant we use \(.*?\)

Comment: working perfectly @vks please submit your answer this way I can validate it

Comment: What encoding are you using? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\(.*?\)
```

Use this to remove all .

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/rX0dM7/5

Answer (score 1):

Use the `u` modifier, add space in the character class and the unicode property is `\p{L}`:

```
$text = preg_replace('#\([A-Z0-9\p{L} ]+\)#ui', '', $text);
//                            __^  __^   __^
```