# CakePHP Console / Shell & special characters (čćčđšž)

Tags: php, mysql, shell, cakephp, character-encoding

due to the migration of web content from Joomla cms in custom cms, built in **CakePHP 2.5.7**, I have to clean the old content, remove tons of unnecessary html tags and so on.

I make a simple shell script that reads from the old database, processing some data and is stored in a new table.

Both of them have the same db encodinig, but when processing and storing data I lose some specific character of the Croatian language (čćđš). The data is regularly saved from the web interface, and do not lose these characters. Also, if we do it through phpmyadmin.

The problem is the console / shell level.

I added the following line in a shell script:

```
$this->out('čćšđČĆŠĐ');
```

The console show the following result:

```
─Ź─ç┼í─Ĺ─î─ć┼á─É
```

How to solve this?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

OS: Windows 7
Language: Croatian

**UPDATE 2:**

joomla db

[image: joomla db]

cakephp db

[image: cakephp db]

**core.php**

```
Configure::write('App.encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

**db config**

```
public $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => 'root',
    'password' => '***********',
    'database' => '*********',
    'encoding' => 'utf8',
);
```

**EDIT 3**

I moved the code from the shell in the contoller.

test:

```
// Read data from joomla db base
$contents = $this->JosContent->find('all');
debug ($contents);
```

return the wrong result, do not display correctly letters čćđ.

> - **edit:** For some strange reason, if I import the whole joomla db, ČĆĐŠŽ letters are not displayed correctly, but if I import only joomla joscontent db table, I have properly display of these letters in html.

The problem remains in the console.

Comment: You might want to add what OS you are running on :)

Comment: Is the "encoding" parameter for your new database connection set correctly to UTF8(in database.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your console encoding to UTF8.

- [Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how/388500#388500)
- https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8
- [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)