# How do you enable european letters in c++ application console?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I'm writing a simple console application but every accented letter like

> è

(used in italian) turns into a different symbol whenever I output it in the console.

Example follows

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int y1 = 20;
    cout << "The number is "<< y1;
    cout << "\nIl numero è "<< y1 <<"\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

How do I tell the compiler I'm using those symbols?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: This most likely have nothing to do with the compiler or your program, and everything to do with the console/terminal program. Not all console/terminal programs can show Unicode or extended ASCII (or other extended character sets).

Comment: If you're on Windows you can set console codepage with `chcp` (DOS command)

Comment: Also read about `wcout`.

Comment: See, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: Configure your system & terminal to use UTF-8

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You also have to be sure that the compiler encodes string literals using UTF-8.  (In the past, this wasn't the case for g++, for example.)  If his only target is Italian, a useful alternative would be ISO 8859-1 (which is what g++ used in the past, and I think is what VS uses); then use code page 1252.

Comment: I guess the caveat is just to avoid using cout and use just wcout, after setting the mode to _O_U16TEXT.