# PHP: Accented chars in Windows command line

Tags: php, windows, character-encoding

I ultimately have a MySQL database I'm connecting to, but for clarity's sake, I've reproduced the issue just using the windows command prompt.  Simply run this command:

```
php -r "echo 'á' . PHP_EOL;"
```

And the output ends up being "**ß**" rather than "**á**" as I would expect.  I'm sure this is some sort of encoding issue, but PHP is not my "native" language and I am really confused as to what is going on here.

Thanks for any clarification you all can give.

PHP Version:   5.5.11

Comment: What encoding is the php file? That is most likely a multi-byte/part character and needs to be UTF8 encoded. Here's a working [example](https://eval.in/292096)

Comment: The PHP file has a different encoding than the Windows command prompt. No duplicate, but related: [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)

Comment: no issues here .`php -r "echo 'á' . PHP_EOL;"`  I got `á`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Windows command prompt, the command "chcp" controls the "code page". `chcp 65001` is supposed to provide utf8, but it seems to need a special charset installed, too.  To set the font in the console window: Right-click on the title of the window → Properties → Font → pick Lucida Console .

More Character set issues (mostly relating to MySQL) are discussed in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll