# Ant xslt build isn't working on windows

Tags: xml, xslt, ant

I am trying to implement a simple xslt transformation using **ant** build. The processor used for transformation is **saxon9.jar**.

Here is the build file made by [this](http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/xslt/ant-saxon/index.html) model:

```html
 <project name="TranformXml" default="TransformAll">
 <target name="xslt2">
 <!-- Transform one file into an HTML file -->
    <xslt in="t1.xml" out="t2.xml" style="t1-t2.xsl" force="true">
    <classpath location="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Exchanger XML Editor 3.3\\lib\\saxon9.jar" />
    </xslt>
 </target>
    
 <target name="TransformAll" depends="xslt2" />
 </project>
```

The command I am using for starting the script is:

> ant build.xml

Of course the working directory is set to where files reside.

This is the repeatedly printed on the command prompt:

> C:\Users\rmrd001\Desktop\XSLTXpath\Examples\2015.10.22>set build=build.xml
>
> C:\Users\rmrd001\Desktop\XSLTXpath\Examples\2015.10.22>ant build.xml
>
> C:\Users\rmrd001\Desktop\XSLTXpath\Examples\2015.10.22>я╗┐
>   ^C'я╗┐' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

when I run the script.

Comment: This appears to be a code page issue in cmd.exe. See [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1259084/1078068).

Comment: What happens if you enter `chcp` in the Command Prompt?

Comment: Also, what happens if you enter `where ant` in the Command Prompt?

Comment: Why did you double the backslashes? That's a convention for languages that use "\" as an escape character, which XML doesn't. In any case, "/" usually works better these days. Having said that, I'm surprised by the symptoms.

Comment: The problem was in my batch file in the same directory with name `build.bat` Sorry I wasted your time.