# Which character encoding is the IPython terminal using?

Tags: python, unicode, terminal, ipython, codepages

I used to think I had this whole encoding stuff pretty figured out. I seem to be wrong because I can't explain what's happening here.

What I was trying to do is to use the [`tabulate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) module to print a nicely formatted table using

```
from tabulate import tabulate
s = tabulate([[1,2],[3,4]], ["x","y"], tablefmt="fancy_grid")
print(s)
```

in IPython 3.5.0's interactive console under Windows 10. I expected the result to be

```
╒═════╤═════╕
│   x │   y │
╞═════╪═════╡
│   1 │   2 │
├─────┼─────┤
│   3 │   4 │
╘═════╧═════╛
```

but instead, I got a

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2552' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Puzzled, I tried to find out where the problem was and looked at the `repr` of the string:

```
In [15]: s
Out[15]: '╒═════╤═════╕\n│   x │   y │\n╞═════╪═════╡\n│   1 │   2 │\n├─────┼─────┤\n│   3 │   4 │\n╘═════╧═════╛'
```

Hmm, all the characters *can* be displayed by the terminal (even the first one that triggered the error).

Just checking some details:

```
In [16]: sys.stdout.encoding
Out[16]: 'cp850'

In [17]: s.encode("cp850")
[...]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2552' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

So which encoding *is* the terminal using? Python says that it's `cp850`, and it tells me that `cp850` doesn't have a `╒` character ([which is true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), it's one of the characters from `cp437` that had to make room for accented letters), but I can *see* it in the terminal window!

To complicate things further, when using the native Python console instead of IPython, the error seems more understandable:

```
>>> s
'\u2552═══\u2564═══\u2555\n│ 1 │ 2 │\n├───┼───┤\n│ 3 │ 4 │\n\u2558═══\u2567═══\u255b'
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'cp850'
>>> print(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2552' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

So at least Python is consistent, but what's happening with IPython?

Comment: If you're seeing the cp437 characters, but Python is saying cp850, then Python is the one that's inconsistent.  Find out what the console is actually set to (see for example [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)).

Comment: @ThomasDickey: I'm seeing *both* - a string like `'╒Í'` that contains characters unique to both charsets (`╒` only in `cp437` and `Í` only in `cp850`) is displayed correctly...

Comment: I can repeat this result in IPython.  The `repr` in IPython should be the same as the `repr` running straight Python, but it's not.

Comment: The Windows console is actually capable of displaying a wider range of characters using the unicode APIs, but `print()` and `sys.stdout` still use the bytes API, which can only deal with character in the active code page. The [win_unicode_console](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console) package tries to get round this. I guess IPython is finding a different default encoding to use when you display `s` - try importing `IPython.utils.encoding.DEFAULT_ENCODING` to see what it has found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython uses OEM code page in the interactive mode like any other Python console program:

```
In [1]: '\u2552'
ERROR - failed to write data to stream: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode=
'w' encoding='cp850'>
Out[1]:

In [2]: !chcp
Active code page: 850
```

The result changes if `pyreadline` is installed (it enables colors in the IPython console among other things):

```
In [1]: '\u2552'
Out[1]: '╒'

In [2]: import sys

In [3]: sys.stdout.encoding
Out[3]: 'cp850'

In [4]: !chcp
Active code page: 850
```

Once `pyreadline` has been installed, IPython's `sys.displayhook` writes the result to readline's console object that uses `WriteConsoleW()` Windows Unicode API that allows to print even unencodable in the current code page Unicode characters (to see them, you might need to configure a (TrueType) font such as Lucida Console in the Windows console).