# Problems With Runtime special chars Show

Tags: java

I have to show well the response of a Command executed using Runtime in java.

```
public static String RunCMDshow(String comando){
        Runtime R = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String resto = "";
        try {
            Process p = R.exec(comando);
            InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String s = null;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                resto = resto + "\n" + s;
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resto;
    }
```

I have Windows in spanish and when It must Recober special Chars like "á,ñ,í"
they take the string like this.

> Estad�sticas de ping para 178.60.128.59:
>       Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0
>       (0% perdidos),
>   Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
>       M�nimo = 8ms, M�ximo = 10ms, Media = 9ms

I must show The result of the comand showing the special chars on a TextPane because I must copy that and I have the problem with commands how returns special chars.

If I must use another way to execute the command I will do that.

Comment: Specify a charset on this line `InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());` see it here: [InputStreamReader Charset constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

Comment: I try using `InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-8"));` But doesen't work well

Comment: If this is a Windows console it should be ISO-8859-1 (I think)

Comment: Ok It works with `InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("IBM00858"));` But the Windows Prompt Must Be UTF-8 I Try with all charsets and I don't know Why IBM00858 works

Comment: I try ISO-8859-1 Too but It doesn't work either

Comment: It seems not so easy! See this post for a super detailed explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using