# Get Windows Command Line charset in java

Tags: java, windows, character-encoding

I've been having problems reading output of windows command line from Java, i'm using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`

I simplified my test case: I have a file called `お読みください.txt`, and i execute the following `command cmd /c dir C:/PATH`

**Note**: The actual command is tasklist, but it's the same result as long as i use Runtime.getRuntime().exec()

```java
String[] cmd = new String[]{ "cmd", "/c", "dir" };
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
BufferedReader stdInput = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
String s, result = "";
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!s.isEmpty()) {
        result += s + "\n";
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

I just get ���ǂ݂�������.txt

I tried with no charset, default, and the other ones; after testing all charsets, i got the one i was looking for: **Shift_JIS**

And that must be because i have set Language for non-Unicode applications as Japanese. systeminfo.exe says **ja;Japanese** for Regional Config.

I can simply use Shift_JIS to read, but it will only work in my computer. What about other system configurations?

The question is, how can i get the correct charset to read Windows Console output?

Comment: Reason 834 not to fork OS specific commands. Why don't you use `File("mydir").listFiles()`?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Sorry, i tried to simplify my example. The actual command is tasklist, and this is only for Windows. The problem is Java doesn't like other encodings.

Answer (score 1):

Base on the answer of [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)

You can execute `cmd /k chcp && pause && exit` to get current code page. Using [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find the mapping Java encoding name.

Comment: won't you have problems reading the output without knowing the charset before?

Comment: The output of `chcp` is a 7bit ASCII string, ex: `Active code page: 437`. There is no encoding problem to parse it.

Comment: In a spnaish windows machine it outputs "Página de códigos activa: <page>"... But I guess you could execute a regex to extract it like ".*:\s*\(d+)"