# Tesseract OCR German Special Characters

Tags: c++, utf-8, console-application, tesseract

iam using tesseract ocr for reading german png images in c++ and i got problems with some special characters like

ß ä ö ü and so on.

Do i need to train tesseract for reading this correct or what need to be done?

[This is the part of the original image read by tesseract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Duv8.jpg)

```
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
```

**UPDATE**

```
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);//changed to german.
SetConsoleCP(1252);//changed to german
wcout << "ÄÖÜ?ß" << endl;

// Open input image with leptonica library
Pix *image = pixRead("D:\\Images\\Document.png");
api->Init("D:\\TesseractBeispiele\\Tessaractbeispiel\\Tessaractbeispiel\\tessdata", "deu");
api->SetImage(image);
api->SetVariable("save_blob_choices", "T");
api->SetRectangle(1000, 3000, 9000, 9000);
api->Recognize(NULL);

// Get OCR result
wcout << api->GetUTF8Text());
```

[After changing the Code below the Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrJR7.png)
the hard coded umlauts will be shown correctly, but the text from the image issnt correct, what do i need to change?

tesseract version is 3.0.2
leptonica version is 1.68

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract can recognize Unicode characters. Your console may have not been configured to display them.

[What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)

[Unicode characters in Windows command line - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how)

Comment: The console almost certainly isn't configured for UTF-8.

Comment: How would you configurate the console for utf8?

Answer (score 0):

```
i don't how to detect German the word from the image in windows environment. but i know how to detect German word to Linux environment. following code may get you some idea.

/*
 * word_OCR.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: Jun 23, 2016
 *      Author: root
 */

#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc ,char **argv)
{
    Pix *image = pixRead(argv[1]);

    if (image == 0) {
        cout << "Cannot load input file!\n";
    }

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
// insted of the passing "eng" pass "deu".
    if (tess.Init("/usr/share/tesseract/tessdata", "deu")) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

    tess.SetImage(image);
    tess.Recognize(0);

    tesseract::ResultIterator *ri = tess.GetIterator();
    tesseract::PageIteratorLevel level = tesseract::RIL_WORD;

    if(ri!=0)
    {
        do {
            const char *word = ri->GetUTF8Text(level);

            cout << word << endl;

            delete []word;

        } while (ri->Next(level));


        delete []ri;
    }

}
one thing you have to take care that pass good resolution image then and then it works fine.
```

Comment: if you want more accuracy than this then you can pass OTSU threshold image in pixeRead(). i am passing normal image in pixRead() right now. pass OTSU threshold image. i developed algorithm for that. . let me know if anybody want.