# nodejs and utf8 output

Tags: node.js, unicode, utf-8, utf-16

I have 'utf8 without bom' script file that produce some output to console. For simplicity lets say it goes like this:

```
console.log("biʧ");
```

the output in windows cmd console or even in Windows Powershell ISE should be obivious:

```
biʧ
```

but isn't! output is:

```
biĘ§
```

Why?

I use notepad++ and Windows Powershell ISE and node 6.x

Comment: Perhaps [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using) are of use?

Comment: @robertklep unfortunatelly not, I use Powershell ISE, which is able to display utf8 characters as default.