# Error outputting unicode text in python 3 to console using Python Tools from MS Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio, python-3.x, encoding

I want to print unicode text to console window without messing with its encoding. I want to replace the characters that could not be printed.

My environment:

- MS Windows 10
- MS Visual Studio 2015
- Python Tools for Visual Studio 2.2.3
- Python 3.4

The problem is when starting the script from MSVS using Python Tools:

- `sys.stdout.encoding` indicates that the encoding is `utf8`
- but `print('\u2013')` will trigger error `'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2013' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>`

When I start the script from `cmd.exe`, `sys.stdout.encoding` indicates correct encoding `cp852`, in this case the error is expected.

I basically want to do this:

```
def safePrint(text):
    e = sys.stdout.encoding
    print(text.encode(e, 'replace').decode(e))
```

so that the characters not supported are replaced, eg.:

```
safePrint(u'a \u2013 b')
```

- shall output `a ? b` for `cp852`
- and `a – b` for `utf-8`

How can I find what encoding is `print` implementation really using?

Comment: Related, if not the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: @theB I don't think so, it is not python related and that is what I am asking... And my problem is probably related only to specific combination running python from Visual Studio via Python Tools.

Comment: This works fine for me in VS Community 2015 14.0.25123 Update 2, with PTVS 2.2.40315.