# wprintf does not output emoji character correctly, but WriteConsoleW does

Tags: c, winapi

I've been testing writing Unicode text (like emojis) to the console for a CLI tool. I've noticed that when using wprintf to output an emoji, it prints out two question marks (��), but when I use WriteConsoleW, it outputs it perfectly fine.

Test code (compiled with MSVC using `/utf-8` and MinGW using `-municode`)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>

#include <Windows.h>

int wmain(int argc, const wchar_t *argv[]) {
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    
    const wchar_t myString[] = L"\n";
    wprintf(L"%s", myString);
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), myString, wcslen(myString), NULL, NULL);
}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Don't know what /utf8 does.  Normally to get anything like that to appear, you need to change the character set for the console.

Comment: @cup /utf-8 makes MSVC treat the input file as UTF-8 instead of ASCII, so the string literal encodes correctly.

Comment: Which console/terminal program are you using? Even if your program correctly handles arbitrary Unicode data it can still be rendered as broken chars; the Windows default console host (`conhost.exe`) [still has issues with Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874063/what-limitations-does-the-windows-console-have-regarding-unicode) - hence MS' pushing people to use Windows Terminal instead of conhost.

Comment: It's not an ansi vs unicode problem (for example if I use a french character such as 'é' the display will be fine), it's because the unicode *codepoint* '' spans more than two bytes. (2x2 actually). The current Windows console supports that (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-unicode-and-utf-8-output-text-buffer/) but not wprintf which will stream  as a sequence of two UCS-2 "characters", not as a whole. Redirect to a file, open it with (a recent) notepad and you'll see it fine. The stream of bytes as a whole is ok.

Comment: On modern Windows, what you can do is just convert the string into UTF-8 and use printf(), ie: `printf("%c%c%c%c\n", 0xF0, 0x9F, 0x98, 0x8A);` should work (remove _setmode call), this is the UTF-8 encoded version of 

Comment: Are you running this on W10 or W11 or something else?

Answer (score 1):

### According to the C language specification

The `wprintf` family of functions differ from their `printf` analogs in two main ways:

- they expect the format to be provided as a wide string, and
- they expect the output medium to be wide-oriented

They *do not* differ in their semantic interpretation of format strings.  In particular, the `%s` conversion specifier means exactly the same thing to `wprintf()` that it does to `printf()`: the corresponding argument is a pointer to the first element of an array of `char` -- not `wchar_t`.  If you want to print a *wide* string then you need to use the appropriate length modifier, yielding `%ls`.  That is,

```
    wprintf(L"%ls", myString);
```

And note that you can do the same with regular `printf`:

```
    printf("%ls", myString);
```

... though it is reasonably likely that you would find differences in the transcoding performed by `printf` and `wprintf`.

This has been the case ever since the introduction of wide-oriented I/O in C99.

### According to Microsoft

Microsoft's C compiler and runtime library are non-conforming in a variety of ways.  Among them is the behavior of the `wprintf` family of functions, in that `wprintf` interprets `%c` and `%s` conversion specifications without width modifiers as corresponding to `wchar_t` and `wchar_t *` arguments, respectively.

It recognizes `%ls` as corresponding to a wide string for all functions, and `%lc` to correspond to a `wchar_t` for all functions (the latter still probably being non-conforming, as the standard says that `%lc` corresponds to a `wint_t`).  They also recognize MS-specific `%hc` and `%hs`, which correspond to `char` and `char *`, respectively for all functions.

| Advice: |
| --- |
| Always use `%ls` and `%lc` conversion specifiers for wide strings and wide characters, with all formatted I/O functions (both regular and wide). That's what the C language requires, and it will work with the MS library. |

### General considerations

C speaks to what data are sent to external devices, but not to what those devices do with the data.  Windows-specific `_setmode()` operates in this space, and various reports suggest that your `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` should make `wprintf` produce do the right thing in your case.  I don't have enough information to determine what's going on -- is it something about your console configuration?  Something about how you're encoding the data in the source file?  Does something work differently in the version of Windows or of the MS CRT that you're using from the ones in which it works?  Is there something in your compiler options that is causing trouble?

In any case, UTF-16 is a horrible encoding.  Where you can get away with it, UTF-8 is preferable in almost every way.  Regular `printf()` doesn't need any special configuration to send UTF-8 strings (it can't distinguish them from any other C string), so using UTF-8-encoded source and configuring the console for UTF-8 mode would be a reasonable approach to try.

Comment: The msvc docs say for the 's' type specifier:"When used with printf functions, specifies a single-byte or multi-byte character string; when used with wprintf functions, specifies a wide-character string", in seeming contradiction to this answer.

Comment: The problem in the question is unrelated to printf vs wprintf and the format specifier. Using `wprintf("%s")` is fine with MSVC

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, the use of `%ls` with `printf` appears to be a Glibc extension, but this answer follows the C language spec with respect to `%s` and `%ls` usage with `wprintf()`.  Microsoft's C implementation is well known to be non-compliant in a variety of respects, and maybe this is one of them, but the output shown in the question is consistent with this answer: note that `wprintf` prints *two* characters, exactly as would be expected for printing each 8-bit half of a 16-bit `wchar_t` separately.  Perhaps MinGW factors in, though it's unclear how the OP is using it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger It looks like it's printing the surrogate pairs. The emoji in question takes up two `wchar_t`s (minus the newline and null).

Comment: If that's the case, @rfl890, then MS's `wprintf` is extra broken.