# ffmpeg list video devices with batch script to variables

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I use the `ffmpeg -stats -hide_banner -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy` command to list all video and audio devices, and I need to get all Alternative name From "DirectShow video devices" (just video devices) with batch script.

I'm start with this: [ffmpeg output parse in batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152588/ffmpeg-output-parse-in-batch-script) (first answer)

Can someone more experienced to help me with this task? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Refer to @Endoro answer here [ffmpeg output parse in batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38152588/ffmpeg-output-parse-in-batch-script).

You can tweak it to get only Video Device List

```bat
@echo off
Title ffmpeg list video devices with batch script to variables
set "VideoDevice="
@For /f tokens^=1^,2delims^=^" %%a in (
'ffmpeg -stats -hide_banner -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /c:"Alternative name"'
) do (
   if not defined VideoDevice (
      set "VideoDevice=%%~b"
   )
)
echo Video Device : "%VideoDevice%"
pause
```