# Can Java change the codepage of its own console?

Tags: java, windows, unicode, console

Echoing the conclusions of https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177904/14731, applications need to invoke `WriteConsoleW` or `chcp` in order to output unicode characters to the Windows console.

I don't want to use JNI so the `WriteConsoleW` approach is out. **Is it possible for a Java application to invoke `chcp` on the console it is running inside of?**

As far as I know, invoking [Runtime.exec("cmd.exe", "/c", "chcp", "65001")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-) will create a new console, change its code-page, and then kill the console. Meaning, the existing console won't be affected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on a hunch, I tried:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "chcp", "65001").inheritIO();
Process p = pb.start();
p.waitFor();
```

and it worked!

`inheritIO()` causes the child process to inherit the parent's `stdout`. When `chcp` modifies the character encoding of the child `stdout` it actually ends up modifying the parent's encoding as well. Great success! :)