# How to read and print Hindi characters from text file in java

Tags: java, swing, utf-8

1. Text file is:

```
MHEM CLASS 1
MHEM CLASS 2
MHEM CLASS 3
MHEM CLASS 4
MHEM CLASS 5
कक्षा  4 रिमझिम
कक्षा  5 रिमझिम
```

2. I need to read character's

```
कक्षा  4 रिमझिम
कक्षा  5 रिमझिम
```

3. The dropdown is showing boxes for Hindi characters and the console is showing question marks: `?????  4 ??????`

[image: 1]

I have tried

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, UTF_8);
```

Comment: That font you are using in the dialogs might not be able to display the Hindi characters

Comment: @g00se I'd be extremely surprised if that is true, that is the default Java font. I would think their default would be one that covers the full set of unicode values.

Comment: Not impossible. It is after all displaying the customary empty box characteristic of missing glyphs. As for the console, trying running it using Powershell (I'm assuming Windows is being used. Please say if not) but before you do so, do `[Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding`

Comment: Much less work required to load a combo from a file: `public DefaultComboBoxModel<String> loadCombo(String path) throws IOException { return new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(Files.lines(Path.of(path)).toArray(String[]::new));`

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all, read something about Unicode and UTF-8.  Possible sources are:

   - [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively
     Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)
   - [What are Unicode, UTF-8, and UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241348/what-are-unicode-utf-8-and-utf-16)
2. Verify that your are reading your text file using the right charset (if the file was created using UTF-8 you must read it using UTF-8).
3. In the dropdown use a font that supports the whole Unicode charset.  You can use Windows' `charmap.exe` to examine a font.
4. Using UTF-8 to write to the console is not enough: you must ensure that the console uses Unicode.  See for example:

   - [How can I use Unicode characters on the Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/how-can-i-use-unicode-characters-on-the-windows-command-line/388500#388500)
   - [Can Java change the codepage of its own console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239033/can-java-change-the-codepage-of-its-own-console)

Comment: But the OP's problem is rendering text in a Swing combo box. Your answer doesn't even mention Swing!

Comment: The question is related both to Swing and the console.  Point #3 of my answer is related to the Swing dropdown, point #4 to the console; points #1 and #2 are prerequisites for both.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any issue over here.

Let's continue with your code and make sure it's written in the way below:

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF_8"); <-- Encoding goes in string here.

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      out.println(line); 
}
```

Over here br is your BufferedReader which is the overloaded constructor of your inputStreamReader. (input txt file)

Tested this setup on my machine and works beautifully.

Let me know if this works. or you need further help. Thanks.

Comment: You claim this _"works beautifully"_, but did you test it using Swing? If so, where is your code? The OP's question is not about a simple Java application; it is specifically about rendering Hindi text in a combo box when using Swing.

Answer (score 0):

Another way this can be done. Read comments in code:

```
public void loadComboItems(javax.swing.JComboBox combo, String filePath) 
                                        throws java.io.FileNotFoundException {
    /* Make sure the supplied Combobox font is `SansSerif` 
       (or any other font that can handle UTF-8):      */
    combo.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 12));
    
    /*
    ===================================================================
    == 'Make sure' the text file had been saved in `UTF-8` format!!! ==
    ===================================================================
    */
    
    // Declare a new DefaultComboBoxModel:
    javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel model = new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel();
    
    /* Read the text file. `Try With Resources` is used here 
       to auto-close the file and free resources once reading 
       has completed:                */
    try (java.util.Scanner reader = new java.util.Scanner(new java.io.FileInputStream(filePath), "UTF-8")) {
        String line;
        // Iterate through the file lines:
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            line = reader.nextLine();
            // Make sure the read in file line is not blank:
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                // Add the file line to model:
                model.addElement(reader.nextLine());
            }
        }
        // Set the new model to the supplied JComboBox:
        combo.setModel(model);
        
        /* Optional - Don't show any item selected within 
           the supplied JComboBox:            */
        combo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    }
}
```

How the above method ***could*** be used:

```
try {
    loadComboItems(jComboBox1, "ComboItems.txt");
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```