# Decode text from console

Tags: c#, .net, console, decode

I try to execute this code:

```
private void Test(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd",
    "/c \"wbadmin start recovert -version:02/26/2014-17:38 -itemtype:File - items:C:\test\"");

        int exitCode;
        using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
        {
            proc.ErrorDataReceived += cmd_Error;
            proc.OutputDataReceived += cmd_DataReceived;
            proc.WaitForExit();

            exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
        }
    }

    private void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data == null) return;

        var source = Encoding.Unicode;
        var target = Encoding.UTF8;

        var sBytes = source.GetBytes(e.Data);
        var tBytes = Encoding.Convert(source, target, sBytes);

        var tString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(tString);
    }
```

But I got this string: "wbadmin 1.0 - ®≠·‚‡„¨•≠‚ ™Æ¨†≠§≠Æ© ·‚‡Æ™® †‡Â®¢†Ê®®"
How can I decode this string?

Comment: could you try `source = Encoding.Utf8;` and `source = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);`?

Comment: You need use Encoding.GetEncoding(850); ,850 is the standart cmd-page.

Comment: 850 not working! var source = Encoding.GetEncoding(850);  var target = Encoding.UTF8; and I got tString == "wbadmin 1.0 - ??®?? ¬¬  ?®¬ ­¤­®© ???®?? ¤«? ???? ???"

Comment: Shouldn't your command line contain **recovery** rather than **recovert**?

Comment: No matter. I need to encode console. I use russian version of Windows Server 2012

Comment: Open console by hands and run chcp command. It will show you your codepage. Then use this codepage as source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing output from the cmd can be a little tricky, since your cmd has its own code page, that is usually equal to system's default locale (you can change it manually, using, for example, [chcp](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) command).

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177904/891715) for details.

When redirecting output, the way that worked for me (tested, also with `wbadmin`) is the following:

1. Get the default locale of your system:

   ```
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
   public static extern int GetSystemDefaultLCID();

   private static int GetCmdCodePage()
   {
       int lcid = GetSystemDefaultLCID();
       var ci = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lcid);
       return ci.TextInfo.OEMCodePage;
   }
   ```
2. Get the corresponding encoding:

   ```
       Encoding enc = null;
       try
       {
           enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(GetCmdCodePage());
       }
       catch (Exception)
       {
           enc = Encoding.GetEncoding(855); // the value for Cyrillic
       }
   ```
3. Set the encoding for the process:

   ```
       if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, @"wbadmin.exe")))
       {
           Console.WriteLine("wbadmin.exe not found");
           return;
       }
       Process pr = new Process();
       ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"wbadmin.exe");
       psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
       psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
       psi.UseShellExecute = false;
       psi.Arguments = "/?"; // prints avaliable commands
       psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
       psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
       psi.Verb = "runas";
       psi.StandardOutputEncoding = enc;
       psi.StandardErrorEncoding = enc;
       pr.StartInfo = psi;
       pr.Start();

       pr.WaitForExit(1000);
       string error = pr.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
       {
           Console.WriteLine("error: " + error);
           pr.Close();
           pr.Dispose();
           return;
       }

       string output = pr.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

       pr.Close();
       pr.Dispose();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seemes to be entirely correct, but meaningless. The fact is that C# string is always UTF-16, no matter what. Your cmd_DataReceived method is converting UTF-16 to byte array, which contains UTF-8 representation of original string, and then converts it back to UTF-16 by calling Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tBytes).

It looks like external programm writes something to console in unknown encoding (UTF-8?), but cmd_DataReceived recieving it already decoded to UTF-16.

I assume, that if you're actualy want to convert your string from UTF-8 to UTF-16, your code shoud look like

```
private void cmd_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data == null) return;

        var source = Encoding.Unicode;
        var target = Encoding.UTF8;

        var sBytes = source.GetBytes(e.Data);

        var tString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(tString);
    }
```