# window 7 and 8. dir>list.txt sends file size unreadable

Tags: cmd, stdout

```
2016-10-18  09:38 PM            32ÿ032 error messages plus.docx
2002-10-18  02:19 PM               195 filestruc.bat
2002-10-18  02:20 PM         1ÿ588ÿ209 filestruc.txt
2004-03-07  03:26 AM           275ÿ792 FileStrucSize.txt
```

Result: The file size is unreadable. How do it solve this problem?

Comment: [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1259084/205233) might have useful information.

Comment: What is the output of the command `chcp`? It appears that the thousands separator has been set to 'ÿ', named LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS. This is 0xFF in Microsoft codepage 1252. What appears as the thousands separator in your regional settings?

Comment: A quick work-around is to state the `/-C` option of `dir`, so the thousands separator is suppressed...