# Python visual output for chessboard

Tags: python, 2d

I'm building a chess program in python.
Currently, my board looks like this:

```
 8  [r] [n] [b] [q] [k] [b] [n] [r] 
 7  [p] [p] [p] [p] [p] [p] [p] [p] 
 6  [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
 5  [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
 4  [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
 3  [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ] 
 2  [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] [P] 
 1  [R] [N] [B] [Q] [K] [B] [N] [R] 
 #   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H
```

This is the current output, but I don't really like it much. You can't tell if a square is black or white, and using caps and lower case letters for the pieces is also not that great. Do you guys maybe have a better idea of how to visualize the board without using third-party libraries?

I tried the chess Unicode characters and colorization in the console, but that doesn't work on Windows.

```
print("\u2657")
>>> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2657' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: If you are stuck with cmd.exe, some of the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using) might help.

Comment: You can use [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) on windows, to show the colors. It works on all platforms. And what is the problem with unicode chess characters?

Comment: I am not able to print these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode . i got it to work on repl.it which runs on linux though.

Comment: @ThuYeinTun I edited the post to show you what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I think your color idea is fine. You can use ANSI escape codes to add color.

Here's an Example I found:

```
print("\033[1;32;40m Bright Green  \n")
```

This will change the color of the text to Bright Green with a Black background. The format is:

`\033[`  = Escape code, this is always the same

`1` = Style, 1 for normal.

`32` = Text colour, 32 for bright green.

`40m` = Background colour, 40 is for black.

Here's a link to the site I found. http://ozzmaker.com/add-colour-to-text-in-python/

The site also has codes for differing colors.

Note: I was using Windows Powershell when running the python code and things seemed to work well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What does >> print('\033[6m' + 'Blink!' + '\x1b[0m') << do on your system? On https://repl.it/repls/VigilantCadetblueSerpent, it blinks, on mine it doesnt.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be blinking on mine either

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to use ANSI escape codes. Here is a great website which shows how to use them:

http://ozzmaker.com/add-colour-to-text-in-python/

This website is mentioned in the above answer and I strongly recommend that you check it out. Also something else you might like to try for your game is to use the escape code `\033c`. This will clear the terminal so each move you can update you chess board.

Here is some more info on escape codes:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

I hope this helps!