# javac does not output unicode on command line

Tags: java, windows, unicode, cmd

Context: Windows 10, cmd.exe, javac 9.0.1.

I have unicode encoded source code. If I run `javac -encoding UTF-8 ...` and I have an error, I just can't get it to display the source correctly.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the cli can print unicode chars just fine.

Comment: I wonder what's the reason for voting to close? This seems a reasonable question to me.

Comment: What if you fix the missing `;` it is telling you about? Does the compiled code then work as you expect?

Comment: That seems to be a funny community here ;-)

Comment: @AndyTurner how's that related to the question? The question was not about the code working or not, it was about javac output problems.

Comment: @eis if javac produces the expected class file, it's simply a display artefact. Otherwise, javac isn't interpreting the code correctly.

Comment: I took it it was recognized by OP that this is a display issue on errors, and otherwise things seem to work. But I guess it could've been explicitly mentioned.

Comment: This is a toy program just to test unicode. I removed the ';' intentionally to get an error on a line that has obviously a lot of unicode chars in it.

Comment: This question has been addressed in almost excessive detail by 
andrewdotn in [what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would appear that javac is not using your terminal's character encoding.

You can specify the character encoding for a JVM using the flag:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...
```

(Or whatever encoding)

Javac is just a thin wrapper around a Java program. You can pass arguments directly to its JVM using the `-J` flag. So:

```
javac -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...
```

Comment: I love you! Worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can know your current(default) encoding by running

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

and you can change default encoding with this property.

For Windows it is usually - `cp1252`,

Long Story, queue from [IBM KB](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_i5_54/rzaha/charenc.htm):

> Internally, the Java virtual machine (JVM) always operates with data
>   in Unicode. However, all data transferred into or out of the JVM is in
>   a format matching the file.encoding property. Data read into the JVM
>   is converted from file.encoding to Unicode and data sent out of the
>   JVM is converted from Unicode to file.encoding.

Comment: `javac` is not my program. The `cp` seems to be correct. As you can see in the picture, I can actually display unicode chars - even obscure ones.

Comment: Try `javac -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 ...`, perhaps?

Comment: @herr.kaste huh, lucky find. Wrote it as an answer anyway.