# Setlocale not working

Tags: c, windows, locale

I'm trying to use the `setlocale` function so I can use Portuguese characters in the Windows console.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    printf("Bem-Vindo ao CALCULADORA SIMULATOR 2018 - FOSÓRIO EDITION\n");
}
```

But this is my output:

> Bem-Vindo ao CALCULADORA SIMULATOR 2018 - FOSÃ"RIO EDITION

Every other text that is written in cmd is shown correctly, only my program's output has this problem.

And looks like any different character is changed to "Ã" plus another random character. For example: `printf("áàóõãÃ\n");` Outputs this:

> Ã¡Ã Ã³ÃµÃ£Ãƒ

Comment: What OS?  It looks like you're trying to write Unicode with a char string function (single-byte / ASCII).

Comment: Try this `setLocale(LC_ALL,"");`. It will set locale as per the location of the OS.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. And I already tryied setLocale(LC_ALL,"");, but it was the same.

Comment: Did you try `setlocale` or `setLocale`?

Comment: [This](http://linguagemc.com.br/localizacao-de-programas-com-locale-h/) can help.

Comment: Are you writing your output to a file or the windows console?

Comment: I'm using setlocale.
@haccks , I've followed this website, but even if I copy the entire code, the problem won't go away.
And I'm outputing in the windows console.

Comment: The `cmd.exe` console is quite poor in displaying non-US characters, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: Okay... I see... But is there any solution for my problem?

Comment: Consider these tips  https://superuser.com/questions/482018/how-to-set-default-charset-in-windows-cmd - change characterset via regedit or via properties

Comment: use `WriteConsoleW` and will be have no any problems at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `setlocale` takes [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) language codes, not the full names of languages in English (plus suffixes that let you, for instance, distinguish Brazilian from European Portuguese; the complete syntax is documented in MSDN under "[Locale Names, Languages, and Country/Region Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/locale-names-languages-and-country-region-strings)").

Second, the output you got, with a string of accented letters `ÓáàóõãÃ` each becoming a two-character sequence starting with `Ã`, is a characteristic [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) pattern for [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) being misinterpreted as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).  UTF-8 is a variable-length encoding for Unicode "codepoints", in which the accented characters you're trying to use each become two-byte sequences; Windows-1252 is a fixed-length encoding, so each of those pairs of bytes is misinterpreted as two characters.  Here's how it happens for those specific characters:

```
character   codepoint    UTF-8 two-byte sequence   Windows-1252
---------   ---------    -----------------------   ------------
Ó           U+00D3       0xC3 0x93                 Ã “
á           U+00E1       0xC3 0xA1                 Ã ¡
à           U+00E0       0xC3 0xA0                 Ã □
ó           U+00F3       0xC3 0xB3                 Ã ³
õ           U+00F5       0xC3 0xB5                 Ã µ
ã           U+00E3       0xC3 0xA3                 Ã £
Ã           U+00C3       0xC3 0x83                 Ã ƒ
```

(the white square on the `à` line is standing in for a non-breaking space)

This is a typical way for "narrow" text output to be mangled by the Windows console.  Windows uses [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) for almost everything internally, which means it often works better to use C's "wide character" library.  Try this program instead:

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt"); // also try "pt_BR"
    wprintf(L"Bem-Vindo ao CALCULADORA SIMULATOR 2018 - FOSÓRIO EDITION\n");
}
```

Note: Most other operating systems were slower to take the Unicode plunge than Windows was, and came to it only after it had become obvious that UTF-8 was a better choice than UTF-16, which means the "wide character" library should be *avoided* on all operating systems except Windows.  Don't worry about this until you need to write a program that works on both Windows and non-Windows.

Comment: I tried "pt", "pt_BR" and "pt-BR", still not working. Is there another solution you can think about? And I'm sure the information you wrote will be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: I discovered that only "Portuguese" changes the output. And any different character is changed by "Ã" plus another random character. For example: printf("áàóõãÃ\n"); Outputs this: "Ã¡Ã Ã³ÃµÃ£Ãƒ".(Will update my question and add this information).

Comment: Did you try with `wprintf` instead of `printf`?

Comment: Sorry.... I've just seen that you're usin "wprintf" and not "printf", I didn't even know this command. It worked perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. The `Ã¡Ã Ã³ÃµÃ£Ãƒ`, by the way, is more of the "UTF-8 being misinterpreted as Windows-1252" mojibake pattern.  I'll edit a more detailed explanation of this into my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem in windows and after change the chcp (850, 860 and 1252) the problem remains.

So I try to use the wprintf but this didn't work too.

I only managed to get it to work when I changed in the  `Settings > Time & Language > Language > Administrative Language Settings > Change System Local > and here select the BETA Unicod UTF-8` and click ok button. After restarting the computer the problem with `printf("áàóõãÃ\n")` are solved.

Answer (score 0):

Call `SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8)` and `SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8)` at the start of your application. This will enable Windows console to display UTF8 characters. And then, you can use `printf`, instead of `wprintf` to print your single-byte strings encoded by UTF-8, and make your code compatible with the world outside of Windows.

Enable "Beta: Use Unicode UFT-8 for worldwide language support" in Windows settings dialogue is not a good solution. You certainly do not want your user to do this in order to run your code. Besides, this option is problematic, it may cause Windows console to display garbage or stop working in certain cases.