# Why is node-emoji rendering unexpected � characters in console?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

A week ago, 11 Aug 2019, I was able to render the characters in Visual Studio Code cmd console correctly without the �, but now 18 Aug 2019, the � is showing along side the emoji. How can I fix it?

```
// app.ts file
import * as emoji from 'node-emoji';

console.log(emoji.get('crossed_fingers'));
console.log(emoji.get('baby_bottle'));
console.log(emoji.get('beer'));
console.log(emoji.get('champagne'));
```

Console output

```
�
�
�
�
```

I tried Visual Studio Code 1.37.1 and also 1.36.1, on Windows 10, both give me same results. I didn't take note what version I was using last week. I also think it could be recent Windows Update causing the problem since there was no system change other then [Windows Update version 1903](https://www.windowscentral.com/whats-new-input-windows-10-may-2019-update) and Visual Studio Code Update, both happened automatically and on different laptops (home and work).

Comment: FYI, I just tried this on requirebin.com and got gibberish characters.

Comment: Works running from the console, using node, on macos.

Comment: @Cully are you using Visual Studio Code? It was working correctly then one day it just decided to print the � character in console.

Comment: It might be an issue with the font used by your console. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using

Comment: No, just using the terminal. Have you tried running directly from the terminal? It could be that your VSC terminal is using the wrong character encoding.

Comment: One other thing to try, `cat` the `node_modules/node-emoji/lib/emoji.json` file in the VSC terminal. See what that shows. `node-emoji` gets the emojis directly from that file.

Comment: The file is UTF-8 encoded, so if you see gibberish in the terminal, it's probably the character encoding/font in your terminal settings.

Comment: @Cully Thank you. I output to a .txt file and the funny characters are gone! OK, so that means the console character encoding is messed up. But I cannot think of any changes done, and the same problem occurs in all Bash, Powershell and CMD, overnight suddenly.