# cmd for loop converting special/foreign characters?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I have a directory with a file with some unusual characters in its name, a simple dir command returns the correct filename:

```
> dir /b
ćłńó.txt
```

I have a very simple for loop running in a command prompt.
However, for some reason the for loop is returning a filename with similar but different characters:

```
> for /f "delims=" %F in ('dir /b') do echo %F
clnó.txt
```

Obviously this is not the desired result.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I think is related to the code page `chcp`. Take a look at this it probably can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using.

Comment: ah, so the answer is to simply use `chcp 65001` before running the command?

Comment: Not sure, I cannot reproduce the error. The best I can recommend is to try it out. Also take a look on https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html to be sure there are no side effects.

Comment: Does it work using `chcp 65001`?