# How can I copy files that contain special characters in CMake when copy_if_different fails?

Tags: windows, utf-8, cmake, character-encoding

I want to copy files/folders containing *special characters* for further use in unit tests and want the files to be overwritten on change.

The OS is `Windows`, The OS Standard Language is `English`, CMake Version is `3.18.0`, The Generator is `Ninja`

This is the relevant content of the `CMakeLists.txt`

```
...
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/data/"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/data/abcüßöϴABC.txt" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/data/abcüßöϴABC.txt"
...
```

This is the output of cmake when running in CMD:

```sh
...
Error copying file (if different) from "D:/source_folder/data/abcÔö£ÔòØÔö£ãÆÔö£├é┬ñÔöñABC.txt" to "D:/binary_folder/data/abcÔö£ÔòØÔö£ãÆÔö£├é┬ñÔöñABC.txt".
Batch file failed at line 28 with errorcode 1
```

According to Notepad++ the `CMakeLists.txt` is UTF-8 encoded and has Windows Line Endings (CR LF).

Using `${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory` I did not see any change in the target file, when the source file was updated.

I found an [Issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/17734) regarding this topic, but I am not sure whether I can circumvent the problem using *different* cmake-commands.

Comment: Do you think `chcp` might change the situation?

Comment: Using chcp 65001 in my scripts before invoking cmake made it work.

Comment: I also assume instead of using `add_custom_command` i shall rather `add_custom_target` and let the original project depend on that custom target, so that copying will run on every build. (This might also enable the copy_directory command solution)

Comment: By the way this [SO Question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using) has an excellent answer regarding codepage (chcp) problems.