# STDIN, STDOUT not streaming correct output when used with pipe in windows

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, fwrite, fread

Platform : Windows

Language : C

I have two programs:

- Program 1 reads `.jpg` file in binary `mode(_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY) ,_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY)` using fread and outputs the using fwrite to stdout.
- Program 2 reads from stdout and outputs to a file( `read/write` done in binary mode). But I can see that output image is corrupted and not same as input.
  I executed `program1.exe | program2.exe` in powershell.

But if I write a program to read a file in binary mode and write it to another file in binary mode, then outputs are same. Problem occurs only when I use `stdin` and `stdout`.

Program 1:

```
int main()
{
    int mode, fd, ret;
    errno_t err;
    int a = _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
    a = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
    //freopen("ooo", "wb", stdout);
    //char in[4096];
    char in[4096];
    char o[100];
    int size = sizeof(in);
    FILE* fpIn, * fpOut, * fp3, * fin;
    //int  a =_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
    int x = sizeof(in);
    fpOut = fopen("out", "wb");
    //int bb = _setmode(_fileno(fpOut), _O_BINARY);
    fin = fopen("pic.jpg", "rb");
    //fin = fopen("in.txt", "rb");
    //a = _setmode(_fileno(fin), _O_BINARY);
    //int length = fread(&in, sizeof(in), 1, stdin);
    int count = 0;
    
    while ((count = fread(in, 1, sizeof(in), fin)) != 0)
    {
        fwrite(in, 1, count, stdout);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    fclose(fpOut);  
}
```

Program 2:

```
int main()
{
int a = _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
     a = _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
    //freopen("ooo.txt", "wb", stdin);
    char in[4096];
    
    int o[100];
    int size = sizeof(in);
    FILE* fpIn, * fpOut, *fp3,*fin;
    //int  a =_setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
    int x = sizeof(in);
    fpOut = fopen("out", "wb");
    //int bb = _setmode(_fileno(fpOut), _O_BINARY);
    fin = fopen("pic.jpg", "rb");
    a = _setmode(_fileno(fin), _O_BINARY);
    //int length = fread(&in, sizeof(in), 1, stdin);
    int count=0;

    while ((count = fread(in, 1, sizeof(in), stdin)) != 0)
        fwrite(in, 1, count, fpOut);


    fclose(fpOut);
}
```

The requirement of program is to allow user to input arbitrary input through stdin and write it to a file.

Comment: Does `while( ( c = fgetc(stdin) ) != EOF ) { fputc(c, stdout); }` not work?  I'm so glad I don't have to work with Windows.

Comment: In program 2, you don’t need to futz with stdout or open fpIn.

Comment: (1) all that commented-out code is confusing. Paste the code you actually used to produce the results you describe. (2) many compilers complain if you ignore the return value of a system library function. You can suppress the warning by assigning the value to a variable you never use but that's not the point: the point is to make sure the function did not indicate an error, and do something (at a minimum, log the error) if it did. Particularly if you suspect  the result.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT***

> Added to address conversation in comments as its relevance may be
> important to OP.    Paying attention to the *current encoding
> settings* of your `cmd.exe` program may be important to do some of the
> things you are asking for.  That topic is discussed in [in this very
> detailed answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177904/645128) and
> serve to explain why you are seeing what you are seeing.

Your only stated requirement is *"The requirement of program is to allow user to input arbitrary input through stdin and write it to a file."*

An example using `fread` and `fwrite` is at bottom, but unless you are *required* to use these, consider a simpler approach...

Borrowing from the comments, this example is the simplest implementation that does exactly what you described you needed.  (And was tested using Windows-10.)

`<ctrl-c>` to exit, then read file `out.txt`...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int c = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(".\\out.txt", "w");
    if(fp)
    {
        while( ( c = fgetc(stdin) ) != EOF ) 
        { 
            fputc(c, stdout); //out to screen
            fputc(c, fp); //to file
        }
        fclose(fp);    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Reading and outputting a binary file is just about as simple, just change the arguments in `fopen()` for binary read/write, and point to an image you want to transfer:

No need of course to use `<cntl-c>`, program will exit when file copy is done.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int c = 0;
    FILE *fpIn = fopen(".\\so_1.jpg", "rb");
    FILE *fp = fopen(".\\out.jpg", "wb");
    if(fp)
    {
        while( ( c = fgetc(fpIn) ) != EOF ) { fputc(c, fp); }
        fclose(fp);    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If it *is* required that you use `fread/fwrite`, then here is a very minimal example of doing exactly the same task using your code with some modifications: (removed calls to `setmode`, `in` buffer sized to file it will contain, removed `while` loop, see in-code comments.)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int count = 0;
    unsigned long len = fsize(".\\so_1.jpg");//start by getting in file size
    char in[len];//create buffer with exact count of bytes in file
    FILE *fpIn = fopen(".\\so_1.jpg", "rb");
    if(fpIn)
    {
        FILE *fpOut = fopen(".\\out.jpg", "wb");
        if(fpOut)
        {
            count = fread(in, 1, sizeof(in), fpIn);//no need for while loop here, just check for > 0 
            if(count > 0)
            {
                fwrite(in, 1, count, fpOut);
            }
            fclose(fpOut);
        }
        fclose(fpIn);
    }
    return 0;
}

unsigned long fsize(char* file)
{
    if(!file) return 0UL;
    FILE * f = fopen(file, "r");
    if(!f) return 0UL;
    if(fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) return 0UL;
    unsigned long len = (unsigned long)ftell(f);
    fclose(f);
    return len;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to write arbitary data from STDIN, these will be no problem when so_1.jpg is read and writted to out.jpg, but when I pass these same input through STDIN then the output wont match. consider simple example, when you try to write ☻(ALT + NUMKEY2) as input to STDIN the out.txt won't contain ☻ instead it will contain some invalid char or no char( due to difference in encoding), same can be observed with some.jpg as input through stdin

Comment: @Brain - keep in mind that the there are many more binary combinations of bits in an `unsigned char` ( `byte`) than are representable within the printable character range visible in `stdout`.  Plainly stated, text streams may be encoded in several ways, but binary data is binary data.  Your example inputs a text representation of `☻(ALT + NUMKEY2)`, but it can be [encoded in more than one way](https://www.puredevsoftware.com/blog/2017/11/17/text-encoding/), (eg `ASCII`, `unicode`, `wide char`) each one leading to a corresponding and different binary stream.  That may be why `input != output`

Comment: `ASCII A` encoding for example is `0x41`, while `EBCDIC` encoding is `0xC1` resulting in different binary values. See updated note at top of my answer.