# What is the format for printing special characters on the console screen?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I wanted to print the intersection symbol "∩" on the console screen and I was wondering if there is a specific code or something that you have to write in the code before the symbol that you are trying to print similar to using backslashes " \ " inside the string declaration to specify quotation marks, etc.
Any help or guidance would be very grateful.

I obviously tried using this at first,

```
cout<<"INTERSECTION (∩)";
```

but this resulted in an unexpected output, there was some weird code instead of the symbol on the console screen.

Comment: No, there is no specific code defined by C++. How you print this (or even if you can print this) will depend on the particular capabilities of the console you are using,

Comment: For example some consoles will support Unicode and UTF-8. If that is the case for you then `"\xE2\x88\xA9"` should do the trick, but YMMV.

Comment: I assume you're on Windows because you tagged this Visual C++. The short answer is it's complicated. [What encoding/code page is cmd.exe using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259084/what-encoding-code-page-is-cmd-exe-using) has a lot of detail about it and some examples that may help you get utf-8 output working, as long as the font you're using contains that character.